# Why do people use standard deviation instead of variance?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

#### **Why do we use standard deviation instead of variance?**

sample variance (S<sup>2</sup>) = [image]

standard deviation (S) = [image]

Comment: In what context?

Answer (score 4):

The Standard Deviation is expressed in the same units as the Mean

More info: [What's the difference between variance and standard deviation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35123/whats-the-difference-between-variance-and-standard-deviation)

Comment: ... and indeed the original values.