# Why squared residuals instead of absolute residuals in OLS estimation?

Tags: regression, estimation, least-squares, residuals

Why are we using the squared residuals instead of the absolute residuals in OLS estimation?

My idea was that we use the square of the error values, so that residuals below the fitted line (which are then negative), would still have to be able to be added up to the positive errors. Otherwise, we could have an error of 0 simply because a huge positive error could cancel with a huge negative error.

So why do we square it, instead of just taking the absolute value? Is that because of the extra penalty for higher errors (instead of 2 being 2 times the error of 1, it is 4 times the error of 1 when we square it).

Comment: OLS estimation basically minimises the sum of squared residuals. From a mathematical point of view, this requires taking the derivative. And there is less trouble in taking the derivative of $x \mapsto x^2$ than in taking the derivative of $x \mapsto |x|$. That's it.

Comment: @ocram: "And there is less trouble in taking the derivative of x↦x2 than in taking the derivative of x↦|x|". I disagree! It's arguably easier to minimize |x-m| than it is to minimize (x-m)^2 (just find $m$ that equalizes $|\{x:x-m>0\}|$ and $|\{x:x-m<0\}|$).

Comment: Related - http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia

Comment: @user603 That's easy for finding a median, but for multiple regression it gets much harder. The OLS solution involves solving a linear system which is as easy as it gets.  (Historically, the first efforts along these lines, c. 1755, indeed minimized the sum of residuals. There's a pretty geometric solution in the univariate model, but I don't think it generalizes to multiple explanatory variables.)

Comment: @PeterEllis I found that question afterwards as well! I do feel that there are some answers with additional information.

Comment: @whuber: as usual, thanks for your insights. One question: 'There's a pretty geometric solution in the univariate model' what does it refer to? --I suppose minimizing the sum of residuals--

Comment: In *The History of Statistics,* Stephen Stigler recounts a 1755 analysis by Roger Boscovich, who argued first that the $L^1$ line passes through the centroid of the points, and then studied how the $L^1$ error varied as a line was rotated through the centroid. By sorting the slopes of the points (relative to the centroid, as an origin), he produced a $O(n\log(n))$ algorithm.  See pp 46-49.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both are done.

Least squares is easier, and the fact that for independent random variables "variances add" means that it's considerably more convenient; for examples, the ability to partition variances is *particularly* handy for comparing nested models. It's somewhat more efficient at the normal (least squares is maximum likelihood), which might seem to be a good justification -- however, some robust estimators with high breakdown can have surprisingly high efficiency at the normal.

But L1 norms are certainly used for regression problems and these days relatively often.

If you use R, you might find the discussion in section 5 here useful:

https://socialsciences.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Books/Companion/appendices/Appendix-Robust-Regression.pdf

(though the stuff before it on M estimation is also relevant, since it's also a special case of that)

Answer (score 27):

I can't help quoting from Huber, *Robust Statistics*, p.10 on this (sorry the quote is too long to fit in a comment):

> Two time-honored measures of scatter are the mean absolute deviation
>
> $$d_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum|x_i-\bar{x}|$$
>
> and the mean square deviation
>
> $$s_n=\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2\right]^{1/2}$$
>
> There was a dispute between Eddington (1914, p.147) and Fisher  (1920,
>   footnote on p. 762) about the relative merits of $d_n$  and
>   $s_n$.[...] Fisher seemingly settled the matter by pointing  out that
>   for normal observations $s_n$ is about 12% more efficient  than $d_n$.

By the relation between the conditional mean $\hat{y}$ and the unconditional 
mean $\bar{x}$ a similar argument applies to the residuals.

Comment: I have to actually learn now about efficiency (and sufficiency, consistency etc), so it really got me curious to find out "12% more efficient" works...

Comment: Essentially, a more efficient estimator is one that needs fewer samples than a less efficient one to achieve a given  accuracy. In this case, if we denote the sample size as $n$, it means that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $d_n$ is $\sqrt{0.12}$  less accurate than $s_n$

Comment: Thanks, seems logical! I'm still curious though to how it can actually be more efficient... and why it is the case. Is there a way to proof that it is more efficient than the sum over all (xi-xbar)^4 then?

Comment: @Dualinity: the intuitive answer is that this because we define efficiency as the expectation of the squared distance between the estimated value $\bar{x}$ and the true value $\mu$ (e.g. $E(\bar{x}-\mu)^2$). By aligning the loss function used in the estimation of the parameter with that used to define efficiency, we maximize the efficiency of the estimated parameter.

Comment: Eddington's approach was empirical and based in real-life data. Fisher's approach was mathematical and based in idealized conditions: normal distributions, error-free measurements. Fisher proof doesn't apply when errors are present. 1% error is enough to invert roles and make $d_n$ more efficient than $s_n$

Comment: @juanrga Yes, and Tukey mentions that Fisher was the only statistician he surveyed in the mid 50's that had any sense of how fragile ('1% of deviating data sampled from a re-scaled normal') this optimality result was.

Answer (score 18):

One thing that has not been mentioned yet is uniqueness.  The least squares approach always produces a single "best" answer if the matrix of explanatory variables is full rank.  When minimizing the sum of the absolute value of the residuals it is possible that there may be an infinite number of lines that all have the same sum of absolute residuals (the minimum).  Which of those line should be used?

Comment: Can you clarify the point you're trying to make, Greg? You seem to be making some statement regarding the coefficient estimates. But, certainly, in OLS the coefficients need not be unique. And, if there is more than one solution, we can immediately conclude there will be an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @cardinal, I was just saying that when using least squares you get a single unique answer, with least absolute value you can get infinite which makes it harder to interpret the results.

Comment: Hi Greg, that is what I'm hoping you can clarify in your answer. You claim you get a single unique answer, but an answer to *what*? (Certainly not to the regression coefficients, necessarily.)

Comment: I am refering to the least squares estimate of the regression coefficients being unique, though I was making the assumption (not originally stated) that the columns of the x matrix are linearly independent, or the x matrix is full rank, or ... (other ways of saying this): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)

Comment: The non-uniqueness could be sorted out with an additional criterion, like requiring $\hat{\beta}$ of minimum norm.

Comment: That is very true. In case of Linear Regression, it never fits a single best fitted line if mod of errors is used as compared to square of error. But it still doesn't clarify that why not power 4 or 8. Why 2??

Comment: @MayukhSarkar, what happened when you tried using 4 or 8?

Comment: @GregSnow Well that's what I am asking. Why not mod but square we understand. But why not we do 4 or 8. Why always 2?

Comment: @MayukhSarkar, and I was suggesting that you simulate various datasets with different amounts of skewness, kurtosis, and whatever the 6th moment is called (include some definite outliers), and use the different criteria (2, 4, 6, whatever) and see how the results behave.  It could be that 4 works just as well as 2, but pre-computers the 2 was much easier to use, but I expect that outliers will affect 4 and 6 much more than 2 (outliers are one reason that some people prefer using absolute value (1 instead of 2).

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. I think it is only that analytical optimization is difficult, numerically it is not.

Comment: @Jonathan, are you referring to my original answer, or one of the later comments?  How would you find the optimum numerically when there are an infinite set of coefficients that give the exact same value for the function that you are trying to optimize?  Certainly it is easy to find one of the values, but starting at a different point could give a different optimum value, do you propose just ignoring this?

Comment: Hi, @Greg Snow, I was not correct at all and you are (didn't think through as I was writing). I down voted wrongly (its locked now); if you make a token change, I can upvote for this correct answer .

Comment: @Jonathan, I included a clarifying statement based on Cardinals comments.  That may open things up for you again.

Answer (score 17):

When the problem is expressed stochastically: $Y=aX+b+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is normally distributed, the maximum likelihood estimate is the OLS estimate - not the minimum absolute deviation (MAD) estimate. So that's nice.

Furthermore, there is a strong link between OLS estimation and linear algebra. $\hat{Y}$ is a linear function of $Y$ --- in fact, it is a projection onto a subspace defined by the independent variables.

A lot of nice things happen with OLS --- MAD, not so much. And as @user603 points out, OLS are more efficient (where the normal model holds). It is less robust, of course.

Comment: Just a remark about notation: usually it's LAD, for [least absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations), and MAD is used for [median absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_absolute_deviation).