# What is energy minimization in machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, computer-vision

I was reading about optimization for an ill-posed problem in computer vision and came across the explanation below about optimization on Wikipedia. What I don't understand is, why do they call this optimization "***Energy minimization***" in Computer Vision?

> An optimization problem can be represented in the following way:
>
> Given: a function $f: A \to R$ from some set $A$ to the real numbers
>
> Sought: an element $x_0$ in $A$ such that $f(x_0) ≤ f(x)$ for all $x$ in $A$
> ("minimization") or such that $f(x_0) ≥ f(x)$ for all $x$ in $A$
> ("maximization").
>
> Such a formulation is called an optimization problem
> or a mathematical programming problem (a term not directly related to
> computer programming, but still in use for example in linear
> programming – see History below). Many real-world and theoretical
> problems may be modeled in this general framework. **Problems formulated
> using this technique in the fields of physics and computer vision may
> refer to the technique as energy minimization, speaking of the value
> of the function $f$ as representing the energy of the system being
> modeled.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Energy-based models are a unified framework for representing many machine learning algorithms.  They interpret inference as minimizing an energy function and learning as minimizing a loss functional.

The energy function is a function of the configuration of latent variables, and the configuration of inputs provided in an example.  Inference typically means finding a low energy configuration, or sampling from the possible configuration so that the probability of choosing a given configuration is a Gibbs distribution.

The loss functional is a function of the model parameters given many examples.  E.g., in a supervised learning problem, your loss is the total error at the targets.  It's sometimes called a "functional" because it's a function of the (parametrized) function that constitutes the model.

Major paper:

Y. LeCun, S. Chopra, R. Hadsell, M. Ranzato, and F. J. Huang, “A tutorial on energy-based learning,” in Predicting Structured Data, MIT Press, 2006.

Also see:

LeCun, Y., & Huang, F. J. (2005). Loss Functions for Discriminative Training of Energy-Based Models. In Proceedings of the 10th International Workshop on Artificial Intelligence and Statistics (AIStats’05). Retrieved from http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-huang-05.pdf

Ranzato, M., Boureau, Y.-L., Chopra, S., & LeCun, Y. (2007). A Unified Energy-Based Framework for Unsupervised Learning. Proc. Conference on AI and Statistics (AI-Stats). Retrieved from http://dblp.uni-trier.de/db/journals/jmlr/jmlrp2.html#RanzatoBCL07

Comment: Can you expand on what "They interpret inference as minimizing an energy function and learning as minimizing a loss function" means? How is an energy function different than a loss function?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer

Comment: @CliffAB  Hopefully that's clearer?

Comment: @NeilG: to be honest, I'm still slightly confused. To me, it sounds like the "energy function" is essentially the same thing as the likelihood function in statistics. Is that a reasonable interpretation or am I missing something more subtle?

Comment: @CliffAB: The energy function can be the log-likelihood in which case the total exponentiated energy is one.  However, that's not even necessary:  Non-probabilistic energy-based models don't worry about this normalization, which can make learning them more efficient than probabilistic models.  This is because it avoids evaluating expensive integrals over the configuration space.

Comment: @NeilG Still hard to understand .  `The energy function is a function of the configuration of latent variables, and the configuration of inputs provided in an example. Inference typically means finding a low energy configuration...`  this sentence is confusing for me (not a native English speaker) . Could you give a real example(maybe iris classification? ) to show what part of a machine learning contain energy function or  energy minimization .

Comment: @Mithril did you read the paper I linked?

Answer (score 2):

In signal detection literature, the energy of a signal $x_t$ is defined as
$$
E = \Sigma x_t^2
$$

When predicting some response y from some features x, a very common and simple way to proceed is to minimise the sum of the squared errors
$$
SSE= \Sigma (y-\hat{y})^2
$$
where $\hat{y}$ is the fitted response. Notice the similarity? The SSE is energy. This energy is minimised by the fitted parameters.

Comment: I think you're confusing the loss with the energy

Comment: I am using the standard definition of energy from [signal processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_(signal_processing)). Computer science / machine learning people do tend to redefine terms, I guess. I come from stats and signal processing background

Comment: Your first formula is an energy function.  The second formula is loss function since it's not a function of the configuration.

Comment: @Neil I'm sure you are using the terminology correctly as defined in the papers you cited. It's just a different terminology from what I'm used to where [SSE is energy](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48725/71428)