# Correlation of residuals and explanatory variables

Tags: regression, residuals, linear

We say that in "standard" OLS regression the residuals $û$ are uncorrelated with $k$-th explanatory variable $x_k$. I know the argument can be intuitively derived from geometry of OLS. There are a lot of interesting articles in this forum on that topic with the bottom line, that the projection is orthogonal.

I am only interested, if that is also true in the following three cases:

- we do a regression without a constant
- $x_k$ is not exogenous
- $E(x_{ik}' u_i) = 0$

I am not quite sure about the first one. I think I've heard, that we need the constant in the model for it to be true. The exogeneity should not matter, as far as I know, i.e. the projection is still orthogonal. And I think the third one does not matter for the question.

Comment: There are sometimes substantive grounds to force a regression through the origin. That can make sense as a reason for insisting on $y = bx$. After all, the laws of physics met at introductory level often have this form. I would need a stronger story for insisting on $y = b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + \cdots + b_p x_p$ and omitting a $b_0$.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks! Not sure if I really get you right. So if I regress y on x without a constant, the projection will still be orthogonal? And what about the other two facts? I assume that exogeneity does only matter for causal interpretation, but not in terms of the construction. And the third one I am still not sure. I think applying the law of iterated expectation yields always 0, if x is exogenous. So that would bring me back to the second statement. Long story short: Is û always uncorrelated with the explanatory variables?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/474102/why-is-the-correlation-between-independent-variables-regressor-and-residuals-zer

The first answer also tells that the fact is only true, when we have a constant in the model.... not sure what to think right now....

Comment: Since you understand the geometry, you don't need to ask about orthogonality: you *know* the residuals are orthogonal to all vectors in the space spanned by the regressor variables.  (That's called the *Normal Equations.*)  What might be confusing is that when that space contains no nonzero constant vectors, orthogonality does not imply *uncorrelated.*

Comment: So in other words, orthogonality holds always? But $xi' ûi = 0$ only holds if we have a constant in the model? Is that not a contradiction?

Comment: I just realized that the original projection matrix P = X (X'X)^-1 X' does not involve any assumption about the error term. Is this what you mean? But that automatically implies the fact $x_i û_i = 0$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not quite sure about the first one. I think I've heard, that we need the constant in the model for it to be true.

See the following example where the residuals clearly correlate with the variable $x$ when we fit a model without constant.

```
set.seed(1)
x = 0:20
y = 5 + x + rnorm(21)
plot(x, y, ylim = c(0,30))
lines(x, predict(lm(y~0+x)))
```

[image: example or residuals correlating with x]

> And I think the third one does not matter for the question.

Consider the covariance (related to the correlation)

$$cov(x,u) = E[xu] - E[x]E[u]$$

The fact that $E[xu] = 0$ does not guarantee zero correlation. In particular if $E[u] \neq 0$ which can happen when there is no intercept.

Orthogonal, as in $x \cdot u = 0$, does not mean uncorrelated, $(x-\bar{x}) \cdot (u - \bar{u}) = 0$

Comment: @marlon, indeed, orthogonality always holds: For `reg <- lm(y~0+x)` we still have, by the OLS properties whuber mentions, that `crossprod(resid(reg),x)` $\approx0$. But, since the mean of the residuals is not zero here (it must be zero when we have a constant, as $\text{cst}'\hat u=0$ is the orthogonality condition for the constant, so that the sum is zero, and hence also the mean). Hence `cor(resid(reg),x)` is not zero.