# Why do we use "Sum of Squared Errors" as loss function in linear regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, linear, loss-functions

What is a loss function? How can we relate the slope of Linear Regression with 
Sum of Squared Errors?

Comment: Those are three questions. Could you bring it back to a single one?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=what+is+a+loss+function

Comment: Have you tried googling what's a loss function? Fot the SSE, check [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia).

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=why+sum+of+squares

Comment: I gave a similar answer here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/46823/10372

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked threads. Please 
read them. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Answer (score -1):

A loss function is a (real-valued) function which typically takes a data set and a certain fitted model.

It is typically used as a measurement to determine goodness-of-fit of the model.
Multiple techniques are based on finding the model that minimizes such loss function.

SSE is used in linear regression because it directly relates to the portion of the variance of outcome $Y$ that is not explained (cannot be contributed) to the difference is the values of (the) predictor(s) $X$. It is a measure of 'predicability' of the $X$'s for the value of $Y$.

The SSE directly relates to the slope of a linear regression model because it is the sum of the squared deviations of a given $(X,Y)$ from $(X,\hat{Y})$ where $\hat{Y}$ is the predicted value based on the model and the given $X$.

Comment: Your answer would be better if you were explicit about how SSE "relates" to unexplained variance and the slope of the regression line.

Comment: This answer seems opaque and lacking in historical context, hence my downvote.