# We square at the variance and SD is it due a link with to Gaussian function?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, mean-absolute-deviation

I had almost same question as "[Why square the difference instead of taking the absolute value in standard deviation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia)". But I also noticed the $\sigma$ or *population standard deviation* is being used in the equations for Gaussian distributions. (although I could not 'perceive' that big equation). So if we have the population mean (a simpler concept) and the population standard deviation, and if we know the dataset follow a Gaussian distribution; we can directly put into the equation for a Gaussian function and can derive the curve.

[image: equation]
equation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)

**It makes me think of** is there the answer of why we use such a squared formulae for variance and Standard deviation? If we did not use that square (*instead if we put 'absolute mean deviation around mean'*); the equation for Gaussian distribution probably would not work.

**So my question is**;  is it we actually use the squared formula for variance and standard deviation so that we can *easily put it into* a Gaussian equation? Is my assumption correct?

PS. Instead of standard deviation, could we use absolute mean deviation for Gaussian distribution?

Comment: You could read Anders Hald, _A History of Parametric Statistical Inference from Bernoulli to Fisher, 1713 to 1935_, §5.5 (Laplace and his failed mean deviation attempt) and §7.2 (Gauss and the normal distribution), or Stephen M. Stigler, _The History of Statistics. The Measurement of Uncerteinty before 1900_, Chap. 3 (Laplace) and Chap. 4 (Gauss) to see when, how and why we started using standard deviation instead of absolute mean deviation.

Comment: For closely related questions and more answers, [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=variance%20square*%20gauss*).