# How would you explain covariance to someone who understands only the mean?

Tags: variance, covariance, intuition, teaching

...assuming that I'm able to augment their knowledge about variance in an intuitive fashion ( [Understanding "variance" intuitively](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17537/understanding-variance-intuitively) ) or by saying: It's the average distance of the data values from the 'mean' - and since variance is in square units, we take the square root to keep the units same and that is called standard deviation.

Let's assume this much is articulated and (hopefully) understood by the 'receiver'. Now what is covariance and how would one explain it in simple English without the use of any mathematical terms/formulae? (I.e., intuitive explanation. ;)

Please note: I do know the formulae and the math behind the concept. I want to be able to 'explain' the same in an easy to understand fashion, without including the math; i.e., what does 'covariance' even mean?

Comment: @Xi'an - 'how' exactly would you define it *via simple linear regression*? I'd really like to know...

Comment: Assuming you already have a scatterplot of your two variables, x *vs.* y, with origin at (0,0), simply draw two lines at x=mean(x) (vertical) and y=mean(x) (horizontal): using this new system of coordinates (origin is at (mean(x),mean(y)), put a "+" sign in the top-right and bottom-left quadrants, a "-" sign in the two other quadrants; you got the sign of the covariance, which is basically [what @Peter said](http://bit.ly/v1WX5s). Scaling the x- and y-units (by SD) lead to a more interpretable summary, as discussed in the [ensuing thread](http://bit.ly/vjOfeG).

Comment: @chl - could you please post that as an answer and maybe use graphics to depict it!

Comment: I found the video on this website to help me as I prefer images over abstract explanations. [Website with video](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/covariance.asp) Specifically this image: [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xGZFv.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xGZFv.png)

Answer (score 511, accepted):

Sometimes we can "augment knowledge" with an unusual or different approach.  I would like this reply to be accessible to kindergartners and also have some fun, so **everybody get out your crayons!**

Given paired $(x,y)$ data, draw their scatterplot.  (The younger students may need a teacher to produce this for them. :-)  Each pair of points $(x_i,y_i)$, $(x_j,y_j)$ in that plot determines a rectangle: it's the smallest rectangle, whose sides are parallel to the axes, containing those points.  Thus the points are either at the upper right and lower left corners (a "positive" relationship) or they are at the upper left and lower right corners (a "negative" relationship).

**Draw all possible such rectangles.** Color them transparently, making the positive rectangles red (say) and the negative rectangles "anti-red" (blue).  In this fashion, wherever rectangles overlap, their colors are either enhanced when they are the same (blue and blue or red and red) or cancel out when they are different.

[image: Positive and negative rectangles]

(*In this illustration of a positive (red) and negative (blue) rectangle, the overlap ought to be white; unfortunately, this software does not have a true "anti-red" color.   The overlap is gray, so it will darken the plot, but on the whole the* net *amount of red is correct.*)

Now we're ready for the explanation of covariance.

**The covariance is the net amount of red in the plot** (treating blue as negative values).

Here are some examples with 32 binormal points drawn from distributions with the given covariances, ordered from most negative (bluest) to most positive (reddest).

[image: Covariance plots, updated 2019]

*They are drawn on common axes to make them comparable.  The rectangles are lightly outlined to help you see them.  This is an updated (2019) version of the original: it uses software that properly cancels the red and cyan colors in overlapping rectangles.*

**Let's deduce some properties of covariance.**  Understanding of these properties will be accessible to anyone who has actually drawn a few of the rectangles. :-)

- **Bilinearity.** Because the amount of red depends on the size of the plot, covariance is directly proportional to the scale on the x-axis and to the scale on the y-axis.
- **Correlation.** Covariance increases as the points approximate an upward sloping line and decreases as the points approximate a downward sloping line.  This is because in the former case most of the rectangles are positive and in the latter case, most are negative.
- **Relationship to linear associations.** Because non-linear associations can create mixtures of positive and negative rectangles, they lead to unpredictable (and not very useful) covariances.  Linear associations can be fully interpreted by means of the preceding two characterizations.
- **Sensitivity to outliers.** A geometric outlier (one point standing away from the mass) will create many large rectangles in association with all the other points.  It alone can create a net positive or negative amount of red in the overall picture.

Incidentally, this definition of covariance differs from the usual one only by a constant of proportionality.  The mathematically inclined will have no trouble performing the algebraic demonstration that the formula given here is always twice the usual covariance.  For a full explanation, see the follow-up thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222091/919.

Comment: Now if only all introductory statistical concepts could be presented to students in this lucid manner …

Comment: @whuber: You should stop editing posts and start posting answers ;) Simply stunning!

Comment: This is beautiful. And very very clear.

Comment: I will do something similar if/when I next teach an introductory statistics class. I wish somebody had done so for me when I was first learning statistics!

Comment: Having done the algebra, I wonder if "universal constant of proportionality (independent of the data set size)" may be misleading, so I want to check if I understood the procedure correctly. For {(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)} there are $3\choose{2}$ = 3 possible rectangles of areas 1, 1 and 4. They're all red so the "covariance" is 6. And {(0,0),(1,1),(1,1),(2,2)} has $4\choose{2}$ = 6 rectangles, all red or zero, of areas 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 and 4 so "covariance" is 8. Is this right? If so it's $\sum_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)(y_i-y_j)$.

Comment: @Silverfish Yes, I should have indicated that the constant was universal after *averaging* the values rather than *summing* them.

Comment: Thanks, this as I suspected. I realised that an extra factor of 2 comes out if the sum is taken over all $i, j$ rather than $i<j$. I think the only other ambiguity is whether the "pair" $(i,i)$ counts - the area of the rectangle is zero, but if averaging rather than summating it clearly makes a difference! Incidentally when I teach covariance I also use the "positive and negative rectangles" approach, but pairing each data points with the _mean point_. I find this makes some of the standard formulae more accessible, but on the whole I prefer your method.

Comment: Do we know if people that invented the concept of covariance and correlation (Pearson i think) had this view in mind ?

Comment: Yeah, I do not know anything about stats. I don't understand how the points on the corners are assigned: `it's the smallest rectangle, whose sides are parallel to the axes, containing those points.` Aren't all sides parallel?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie This isn't about statistics, it's about geometry: You can construct plenty of rectangles whose sides are *not* parallel to the coordinate axes.

Comment: Coming from a programming background, I still have no idea :S

Comment: I think a reason as to ***what*** the co-variance is used for in applications would not hurt the mind of many.

Comment: @Karl Its relationship to linear associations and correlation coefficients (see the bullet points at the end) ought to be enough!

Comment: @whuber: this is a genious explanation for covariance ! I must give (+1) (I would like to give more).  One question, why do you draw rectangles based on the points $(x_i, y_i)$ and $(x_j, y_j)$ and not on $(x_i, y_i)$ and $(\bar{x}, \bar{y})$ ?

Comment: @fcoppens Indeed, there is a traditional explanation that proceeds as you suggest.  I thought of this one because I did not want to introduce an idea that is unnecessary--namely, constructing the centroid $(\bar x, \bar y)$.  That would make the explanation inaccessible to the five-year-old with a box of crayons. Some of the conclusions I drew at the end would not be immediate, either. For example, it would no longer be quite so obvious that the covariance is sensitive to certain kinds of outliers.

Comment: I couldn't get the sciguides link to load. That may just be a problem with me but you might like to double-check it at some convenient time.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks--it doesn't work for me, either.  I'll delete the reference.  For the record, here's the deleted text: 
*(The original version of this post has led to the creation of a simplified graphical rendition of the underlying idea. It is accompanied by an admirably clear, step-by-step explanation.  Please check it out at http://sciguides.com/guides/covariance/. For additional explanation also see the answer posted here by [arthur.00](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/111296).)*

Comment: Hi @whuber, I was looking at your graph a year ago, looking to decipher something highly complex , or at least presumably very complex because I wanted to , and now going back to your reading, it is absolutely simple. Many many thanks for such a pedagogical explanation. One thing though however and this something I've noted a lot in a lot of math/stats explanation: Tons of teachers are not mentionning that sometimes it is up to the do-er to choose in a arbitral manner the points and to be honest with you, I had to fight a bit to get that. But once done, 1/2

Comment: @whuber your explanation and the implicit deductions just made perfect sense. Thanks again 2/2

Comment: It seems many people find this a simple explanation, unfortunately I failed to understand covariance by reading this at first. After reading about covariance in other places, such as [this Quora's question](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-correlation-and-covariance), then I was able to read this again and understand better the rectangles example. I personally think explaining *covariance properties* such as **Bilinearity** and **Relationship to linear associations** is not intuitive (as OP asked), at least to me (maybe I'm way too mediocre). Still appreciatte the effort +1

Comment: I'm with @Alisson and Karl Morrison, I'm lost. Super thanks for all the time you put into making the answer but I didn't follow at all. It's full of math jargon like *bilinearity* and *Relationship to linear associations*. I still have no idea what covariance is. Is it related to points or lines? Are we pulling pairs of points or all possible pairs? If the points are A,B,C,D are we doing (A,B) and (C,D) or are we doing (A,B),(A,C),(A,D),(B,C),(B,D),(C,D)? I guess I first need to be a math wiz, then I'll understand this.

Comment: Thanks. Are both the x_i, y_i random (binormal) distributed or is x_i a given , a mathematical ( non-random) variable?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i still need one clarification. If the x,y pairs are (-1,-1), (0,0), and (1,1) - there will be in total 3 rectangles. 1 red and 1 non-red. And the 3rd rectangles between connecting (-1,-1) and (1,1) - is it positive or negative ? Or will it be partly positive and partly negative  ?

Comment: @Praveen Yes, those three points determine three (nondegenerate) rectangles--and *all* are red.

Comment: I am unable to prove the equivalence mentioned in the last statement... Could you please perhaps give a hint or a sketch of the proof?

Comment: @FreezingFire A reasonable request.  I have included a demonstration in another answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222091/919.

Comment: I've tried several examples by hand and there is an error with this answer. The sum of the areas need to be divided by 2 times the number of rectangles drawn (N*(N-1)). In a way, covariance is taking the average area (considering the positive/negative signs) of each rectangle drawn, and then dividing by 2. The author may have actually done this for their calculations but this is not mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Kenny Thank you for your comment.  This is no error: it is by design and it is mentioned.  I explain the distinction in the last paragraph.  I did not want to distract anyone with this detail, which is discussed in several other threads here on CV.

Comment: is @Kenny's remark mentioned in your answer? in the last paragraph, you say that the constant of proportionality is "independent of the data set size" -- that seems different than the remark, which says that the constant of proportionality depends on the data set size

Comment: @Richard Good point: I could have stated this more clearly, especially because Kenny's characterization of the constant is wrong (it's off by a factor of 2).  I'll think about how to clarify that in the text.  Since this post has been around so long, I want to proceed carefully and change it as little as possible.

Comment: Thanks. I think saying that the constant of proportionality depends on the dataset size (rather than being independent of it) might be correct? If it is correct, that would be sufficient. I think that is intuitive, since the net sum of the areas is not taking an average, and covariance is an average.

Comment: @Richard The underlying idea is there is a denominator that obviously *ought* to depend on dataset size: namely, the number of pairs of diagonally opposite vertices that can be formed, $\binom{n}{2}.$  Upon dividing by that, there is a *universal* constant, independent of $n,$ that will produce the covariance.  (And that constant therefore is readily computable by doing the calculation with a tiny dataset :-).

Comment: Maybe then my confusion is in the sentence you write "The covariance is the net amount of red in the plot," which seems false, and I think the correct statement is "The covariance is the net amount of red in the plot, divided by twice the number of rectangles you drew." Which isn't that much more complicated of a statement.

Comment: I am calculating the covariance of 2 stock price movements. So covariance is 1 dimensional to me. Why is @whuber's answer is 2 dimensional? How can I change it to 1 dimensional covariance problem of mine?

Comment: how are the 2 dots comprising a square decided?

Comment: @Eiffel (1) Two stocks, two dimensions.  (2) Take two dots in the plane: there's only one rectangle that has them as diagonally opposite endpoints.  Its top and bottom span the range of the first coordinates of the dots while its left and right sides span the range of the second coordinates.

Comment: my professor used that very diagram :)

Answer (score 89):

To elaborate on my comment, I used to teach the covariance as a measure of the (average) co-variation between two variables, say $x$ and $y$.

It is useful to recall the basic formula (simple to explain, no need to talk about mathematical expectancies for an introductory course):

$$
\text{cov}(x,y)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)
$$

so that we clearly see that each observation, $(x_i,y_i)$, might contribute positively or negatively to the covariance, depending on the product of their deviation from the mean of the two variables, $\bar x$ and $\bar y$. Note that I do not speak of magnitude here, but simply of the sign of the contribution of the ith observation.

This is what I've depicted in the following diagrams. Artificial data were generated using a linear model (left, $y = 1.2x + \varepsilon$; right, $y = 0.1x + \varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ were drawn from a gaussian distribution with zero mean and $\text{SD}=2$, and $x$ from an uniform distribution on the interval $[0,20]$).

[image]

The vertical and horizontal bars represent the mean of $x$ and $y$, respectively. That mean that instead of "looking at individual observations" from the origin $(0,0)$, we can do it from $(\bar x, \bar y)$. This just amounts to a translation on the x- and y-axis. In this new coordinate system, every observation that is located in the upper-right or lower-left quadrant contributes positively to the covariance, whereas observations located in the two other quadrants contribute negatively to it. In the first case (left), the covariance equals 30.11 and the distribution in the four quadrants is given below:

```
   +  -
+ 30  2
-  0 28
```

Clearly, when the $x_i$'s are above their mean, so do the corresponding $y_i$'s (wrt. $\bar y$). Eye-balling the shape of the 2D cloud of points, when $x$ values increase $y$ values tend to increase too. (But remember we could also use the fact that there is a clear relationship between the covariance and the slope of the regression line, i.e. $b=\text{Cov}(x,y)/\text{Var}(x)$.)

In the second case (right, same $x_i$), the covariance equals 3.54 and the distribution across quadrants is more "homogeneous" as shown below:

```
   +  -
+ 18 14
- 12 16
```

In other words, there is an increased number of case where the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s do not covary in the same direction wrt. their means.

Note that we could reduce the covariance by scaling either $x$ or $y$. In the left panel, the covariance of $(x/10,y)$ (or $(x,y/10)$) is reduced by a ten fold amount (3.01). Since the units of measurement and the spread of $x$ and $y$ (relative to their means) make it difficult to interpret the value of the covariance in absolute terms, we generally scale both variables by their standard deviations and get the correlation coefficient. This means that in addition to re-centering our $(x,y)$ scatterplot to $(\bar x, \bar y)$ we also scale the x- and y-unit in terms of standard deviation, which leads to a more interpretable measure of the linear covariation between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 48):

I loved @whuber 's answer - before I only had a vague idea in my mind of how covariance could be visualised, but those rectangle plots are genius.

However since the formula for covariance involves the mean, and the OP's original question did state that the 'receiver' does understand the concept of the mean, I thought I would have a crack at adapting @whuber's rectangle plots to compare each data point to the means of x and y, as this more represents what's going on in the covariance formula. I thought it actually ended up looking fairly intuitive:
[image: "Covariance graphs for a variables with different correlations"]

The blue dot in the middle of each plot is the mean of x (x_mean) and mean of y (y_mean).

The rectangles are comparing the value of x - x_mean and y - y_mean for each data point.

The rectangle is green when either:

- both x and y are greater than their respective means
- both x and y are less than their respective means

The rectangle is red when either:

- x is greater than x_mean but y is less than y_mean
- x is less than x_mean but y is greater than y_mean

Covariance (and correlation) can be both strongly negative and strongly positive. When the graph is dominated by one colour more than the other, it means that the data mostly follows a consistent pattern.

- If the graph has lots more green than red, it means that y generally increases
  when x increases.
- If the graph has lots more red than green, it means that y generally decreases when x increases.
- If the graph isn't dominated by one colour or the other, it means that there isn't much of a pattern to how x and y relate to each other.

The actual value of the covariance for two different variables x and y, is basically the sum of all the green area minus all the red area, then divided by the total number of data points - effectively the average greenness-vs-redness of the graph.

How does that sound/look?

Comment: Just to make sure, the blue dot in the middle is the average of ALL the points?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It's different in each of the 4 graphs as they are of different sets of data.

Comment: Thanks for this! One confusing thing about this is that you have sort of flipped (although not exactly) the color scheme from @whuber's answer. In trying to wrap my head around the concept, that gave some cognitive whiplash.

Comment: +1 I prefer your explanation, especially the second-to-last sentence, thank you so much

Comment: How do you draw the plot? Did you use Python to draw it? If you did, can you kindly share your code, please? @capohugo

Comment: @Eiffelbear You can draw rectangles using [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) and the multiple panels with [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html). Making a plot like this with `matplotlib` is pretty straightforward. Look up the necessary documentation.

Comment: Was there a reason you switched the meaning of red from whuber's?

Comment: @Kirsten it's likely just a cultural background thing, but I found the idea of `blue=negative` / `red=positive` deeply unintuitive and jarring. 
I am much more used to `red=negative` in the context of displaying the sign of numbers, while blue & green are natural positive colours (e.g. traffic lights).
I'm a native english speaker from Australia. I'm guessing people from different backgrounds would have different colour/number associations.

Answer (score 41):

Covariance is a measure of how much one variable goes up when the other goes up.

Comment: Is it always in the 'same' direction? Also, does it apply for inverse relations too (i.e., as one goes up the other goes down)?

Comment: I think that that's what determines the sign of covariance...as per my posted 'answer'

Comment: @nupul Well, the opposite of "up" is "down" and the opposite of "positive" is "negative".  I tried to give a one sentence answer. Yours is much more complete.  Even your "how two variables change together" is more complete, but, I think, a little harder to understand.

Comment: +1 for fitting it in a single, simple sentence, but isn't that correlation? I mean, I know greater cov=> greater corr, but with that sentence, I'd expect something like "80%" as an answer, which corresponds to corr=0.8. Doesn't cov also describe the variance within the data? ie. "Covariance is proportional to how much one variable goes up when the other goes up, and also proportional to the spread of the data in both variables", or something?

Comment: @naught101 Covariance is in the original units, isn't it?

Comment: That's right, Peter, which is why @naught101 made that comment: you description sounds like a rate of change, whose units will therefore be [units of one variable] / [units of the other variable] (if we interpret it like a derivative) or will just be [units of one variable] (if we interpret as a pure difference). Those are neither covariance (whose unit of measure is the product of the units for the two variables) nor correlation (which is unitless).

Comment: @nbro The only problem is that it's wrong.  (And not just a little bit: this is not a nit-pick.)

Comment: @nbro Consider any concrete example: suppose you know the covariance of variables $X$ and $Y$ is $1,$ for instance.  Even with the most generous understanding of "variable" and "go up," could you tell from that information alone how much $Y$ goes up when $X$ goes up by a given amount?  The answer is no: the *only* information it gives you is that $Y$ would tend to increase.  In this post Peter has confused the covariance with a regression coefficient (of which there are two, by the way, and they usually are different).

Comment: @nbro Covariance is the second central moment of a bivariate random variable.  And *that* returns us to the beginning: how would one convey this precise definition to the proverbial five-year-old?  As always, there's a trade-off between economy of expression and accuracy: when the audience doesn't have the concepts or language needed to understand something immediately, somehow you have to weave in an explanation of that background along with your description.  Doing it *right* requires some elaboration.  Usually there's no shortcut.

Answer (score 18):

I *am* answering my own question, but I thought It'd be great for the people coming across this post to check out some of the explanations [on this page](http://askville.amazon.com/covariance-apply-statistics/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=6460933).

I'm paraphrasing one of the very well articulated answers (by a user'Zhop'). I'm doing so in case if that site shuts down or the page gets taken down when someone eons from now accesses this post ;)

> Covariance is a measure of how much two variables change together.
>   Compare this to Variance, which is just the range over which one
>   measure (or variable) varies.
>
> In studying social patterns, you might hypothesize that wealthier
>   people are likely to be more educated, so you'd try to see how closely
>   measures of wealth and education stay together.  You would use a
>   measure of covariance to determine this.
>
> ...
>
> I'm not sure what you mean when you ask how does it apply to
>   statistics. It is one measure taught in many stats classes.  Did you
>   mean, when should you use it?
>
> You use it when you want to see how much two or more variables change
>   in relation to each other.
>
> Think of people on a team.  Look at how they vary in geographic
>   location compared to each other.  When the team is playing or
>   practicing, the distance between individual members is very small and
>   we would say they are in the same location.  And when their location
>   changes, it changes for all individuals together (say, travelling on a
>   bus to a game). In this situation, we would say they have a high level
>   of covariance.  But when they aren't playing, then the covariance rate
>   is likely to be pretty low, because they are all going to different
>   places at different rates of speed.
>
> So you can predict one team member's location, based on another team
>   member's location when they are practicing or playing a game with a
>   high degree of accuracy.  The covariance measurement would be close to
>   1, I believe.  But when they are not practicing or playing, you would
>   have a much smaller chance of predicting one person's location, based
>   on a team member's location.   It would be close to zero, probably,
>   although not zero, since sometimes team members will be friends, and
>   might go places together on their own time.
>
> However, if you randomly selected individuals in the United States,
>   and tried to use one of them to predict the other's locations, you'd
>   probably find the covariance was zero.  In other words, there is
>   absolutely no relation between one randomly selected person's location
>   in the US, and another's.

Adding another one (by 'CatofGrey') that helps augment the intuition:

> In probability theory and statistics, covariance is the measure of how
>   much two random variables vary together (as distinct from variance,
>   which measures how much a single variable varies).
>
> If two variables tend to vary together (that is, when one of them is
>   above its expected value, then the other variable tends to be above
>   its expected value too), then the covariance between the two variables
>   will be positive. On the other hand, if one of them is above its
>   expected value and the other variable tends to be below its expected
>   value, then the covariance between the two variables will be negative.

These two together have made me understand covariance as I've never understood it before! Simply amazing!!

Comment: Although these descriptions are qualitatively suggestive, sadly they are incomplete: they neither distinguish covariance from correlation (the first description appears to confuse the two, in fact), nor do they bring out the fundamental assumption of *linear* co-variation.  Also, neither addresses the important aspect that covariance depends (linearly) on the scale of each variable.

Comment: @whuber - agreed! And hence haven't marked mine as the answer :) (not as yet ;)

Answer (score 16):

I really like Whuber's answer, so I gathered some more resources. Covariance describes both how far the variables are spread out, and the nature of their relationship.

Covariance uses rectangles to describe how far away an observation is from the mean on a scatter graph:

- If a rectangle has long sides and a high width or short sides and a short width, it provides evidence that the two variables move together.
- If a rectangle has two sides that are relatively long for that variables, and two sides that are relatively short for the other variable, this observation provides evidence the variables do not move together very well.
- If the rectangle is in the 2nd or 4th quadrant, then when one variable is greater than the mean, the other is less than the mean. An increase in one variable is associated with a decrease in the other.

I found a cool visualization of this at http://sciguides.com/guides/covariance/, It explains what covariance is if you just know the mean. [link via the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150406005201/http://sciguides.com/guides/covariance/)

Comment: +1 Nice explanation (especially that introductory one-sentence summary). The link is interesting. Since it has no archive on the [Wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/http://creatorguides.com) it likely is new. Because it so closely parallels my (three-year-old) answer, right down to the choice of red for positive and blue for negative relationships, I suspect it is an (unattributed) derivative of the material on this site.

Comment: The "cool visualization" link has died... .

Comment: @whuber: Thanks again. I am trying to prove analytically that points on the circle, i.e., y = \pm (1-x^2)  are uncorrelated. For  that, I need the joint distribution (X,Y). Can you help me figure it out?

Comment: @MSIS That's not possible to figure out, because there are a very great number of possible distributions on the circle.  But if you are referring to the *uniform* distribution, there's nothing to calculate, because (as I recall remarking in your thread at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/414365/919) the correlation coefficient must equal its own negative, *QED.*

Comment: @whuber: Would this method work for other pairs such as (X,X^2)?

Comment: @MSIS If "method" means "an appeal to symmetry," the answer is that it will work but the result depends on how $X$ is distributed.  As an example, if $X$ is  a random variable with a distribution symmetric about $0$ with finite fourth moment, then $X$ and $X^2$ must be uncorrelated. As a non-example, if $X$ has a distribution symmetric about $1,$ then nothing general can be said about the correlation of $X$ and $X^2:$ indeed, it could be any value between $-1$ and $1$ inclusive.

Comment: @whuber :  EDITThanks for your patience, a last one , please:  Do you know what joint distribution is assumed when the claim is made of the variables being uncorrelated? You were right, I was careless in not  scoping this assumption. It seems hard to figure out what the joint should be so that  \int xy f_{XY}(x,y) - \int x* \mu_X *\int y*\mu_Y =0.

Comment: @MSIS Usually, in the absence of an explicit distribution, and almost always in a purely mathematical context, one assumes that a uniform distribution is meant.  In the case of a geometrical circle parameterized by an angle $\alpha,$ the basic events are of the form $a\lt\alpha\le b$ and their probabilities equal $((b-a) \operatorname{mod} 2\pi)/(2\pi).$

Answer (score 14):

Here's another attempt to explain covariance with a picture.  Every panel in the picture below contains 50 points simulated from a bivariate distribution with correlation between x & y of 0.8 and variances as shown in the row and column labels.  The covariance is shown in the lower-right corner of each panel.

[image: Different covariances, all with correlation = 0.8]

Anyone interested in improving this...here's the R code:

```
library(mvtnorm)

rowvars <- colvars <- c(10,20,30,40,50)

all <- NULL
for(i in 1:length(colvars)){
  colvar <- colvars[i]
  for(j in 1:length(rowvars)){
    set.seed(303)  # Put seed here to show same data in each panel
    rowvar <- rowvars[j]
    # Simulate 50 points, corr=0.8
    sig <- matrix(c(rowvar, .8*sqrt(rowvar)*sqrt(colvar), .8*sqrt(rowvar)*sqrt(colvar), colvar), nrow=2)
    yy <- rmvnorm(50, mean=c(0,0), sig)
    dati <- data.frame(i=i, j=j, colvar=colvar, rowvar=rowvar, covar=.8*sqrt(rowvar)*sqrt(colvar), yy)
    all <- rbind(all, dati)
  }
}
names(all) <- c('i','j','colvar','rowvar','covar','x','y')
all <- transform(all, colvar=factor(colvar), rowvar=factor(rowvar))
library(latticeExtra)
useOuterStrips(xyplot(y~x|colvar*rowvar, all, cov=all$covar,
                      panel=function(x,y,subscripts, cov,...){
                        panel.xyplot(x,y,...)
                        print(cor(x,y))
                        ltext(14,-12, round(cov[subscripts][1],0))
                      }))
```

Answer (score 5):

I would simply explain correlation which is pretty intuitive.  I would say "Correlation measures the strength of relationship between two variables X and Y.  Correlation is between -1 and 1 and will be close to 1 in absolute value when the relationship is strong.  Covariance is just the correlation multiplied by the standard deviations of the two variables.  So while correlation is dimensionless, covariance is in the product of the units for variable X and variable Y.

Comment: This seems inadequate because there is no mention of linearity. X and Y could have a strong quadratic relationship but have a correlation of zero.

Answer (score 4):

Variance is the degree by which a random vairable changes with respect to its expected value Owing to the stochastic nature of be underlying process the random variable represents.

Covariance is the degree by which two different random variables change with respect to each other. This could happen when random variables are driven by the same underlying process, or derivatives thereof. Either processes represented by these random variables are affecting each other, or it's the same process but one of the random variables is derived from the other.

Answer (score 2):

Two variables that would have a high positive covariance (correlation) would be the number of people in a room, and the number of fingers that are in the room.  (As the number of people increases, we expect the number of fingers to increase as well.)

Something that might have a negative covariance (correlation) would be a person's age, and the number of hair follicles on their head. Or, the number of zits on a person's face (in a certain age group), and how many dates they have in a week.  We expect people with more years to have less hair, and people with more acne to have less dates.. These are negatively correlated.

Comment: Covariance is not necessarily interchangeable with correlation - the former is very unit dependent. Correlation is a number between -1 and 1 a unit-less scalar representing the 'strength' of the covariance IMO and that's not clear from your answer

Comment: Downvoted as the answer implies that covariance and correlation can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

Covariance is a statistical measure that describes the relationship between two variables. If two variables have a positive covariance, it means that they tend to increase or decrease together. If they have a negative covariance, it means that they tend to move in opposite directions. If they have a covariance of zero, it means that they are independent and do not affect each other.

To explain covariance to someone who understands only the mean, you could start by explaining that the mean is a measure of the central tendency of a distribution. The mean tells you the average value of a set of numbers.

Covariance, on the other hand, measures how two variables vary together. It tells you whether they tend to increase or decrease together, or whether they move in opposite directions.

For example, suppose you have two sets of numbers, X and Y. The mean of X tells you the average value of X, and the mean of Y tells you the average value of Y. If the covariance between X and Y is positive, it means that when X is above its mean, Y tends to be above its mean as well. And when X is below its mean, Y tends to be below its mean as well. If the covariance is negative, it means that when X is above its mean, Y tends to be below its mean, and vice versa. If the covariance is zero, it means that there is no relationship between X and Y.

So, in summary, covariance measures the tendency of two variables to vary together, and can be positive, negative, or zero.