# How to illustrate the "Coefficient of determination" using graphics (preferably using R)?

Tags: r, regression, data-visualization, r-squared

I came across this nice illustration of the "Coefficient of determination" ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Coefficient_of_Determination.svg)):

[image]

Which leads me to ask two questions:

1. How to do it with R? (I guess my main question would be how to deal with the opacity)
2. Are there other interesting/useful visualizations of the "Coefficient of determination"?  (and again, is there an easy way to make them in R?)

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, where did you find that illustration?

Comment: I forgot to link, here is the source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Coefficient_of_Determination.svg

Comment: re #2: A different graphical method to explain covariance (and therefore, in an obvious way, the correlation coefficient) appears at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18200.  However, I used *Mathematica* to make the illustration, not R, and even *Mathematica* could not quite do what I wanted (which is to get complementary overlapping colors to cancel rather than add).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `R`, use the `alpha` argument to `hsv()`:

```
# Create test data.
# (These parameters produce a bunch of multiple overlaps.)
set.seed(17)
x <- (1:24)*2
y <- 24 + x/8 + 8 * rnorm(length(x))

# Draw the figure.
plot(x, y, pch=19, cex=0.8)   # Plot the points
fit <- lm(y ~ x)              # Find the least squares line
abline(fit)                   # Plot the line
u <- mapply(function(x,y,r) rect(x, y, x-r, y-r, col=hsv(1,alpha=0.1), border=NA), 
     x, y, fit$residuals)     # Plot the squares
```

[image: Covariance plot]

Comment: ggplot2 also has an alpha parameter that would do the same thing.

Comment: @PaulHurleyuk `lattice` too :)