Is there a way to statistically test/show that values in a histogram are less likely to occur?
I'm seeking help interpreting this histogram. Is there a statistical test or way to confidently say that groups greater than X are less likely to occur? Preferably something I could run in R. Just from eyeballing it, it looks like group size greater than 11 is less common. Data is a list of animal groups of varying group sizes, 88 total observations. Mean is 6.6, median is 6.


You can calculate any quantile you like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile You can also calculate the uncertainty in that quantile. I'm not sure that answers your question though: could you add more detail about your specific problem?

I recommend running ?ecdf.

As I understand it, your histogram shows group sizes from 2 to 18 and although your bars would benefit from a lighter fill colour, your bin width is appropriately 1. So, you have all the information from the data about what sizes are likely to occur. You need science, the context of your data, not statistics, to say whether a group size of 18 or more is possible. At a guess the sizes not observed such as 14, 16, 17 are all possible.

The histogram already shows this. Perhaps you want to test some hypothesis? Or estimate soem parameter? Please provide details of those.

If you want to run a statistical test, you will need to specify a null hypothesis. For instance, you could use the null hypothesis of equally distributed group sizes. Then you can test whether observing only 2 groups of size at least 15 would lead you to reject the null hypothesis (e.g., using a chi^2 test). But note that your null hypothesis should be motivated by your domain knowledge and scientific question, and should really be specified before you collect data. (Otherwise, it's too easy to HARK, hypothesize after results are known, which invalidates all tests.)

Following @mkt, it's likely https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/99829 answers your question.  Analyzing the histogram alone is fraught, because its details often are arbitrary: see glen_b's great answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51753/919.  Formulating your hypothesis based on the data, such as an observation of a gap in the histogram, is even more fraught: search our site for data snooping or data dredging.
