# Confidence intervals for median

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-error, median

I have a distribution of samples with a small number of values in each one (less than $10$). I have calculated the median for each sample, which I want to compare with a model and obtain the difference between the model and the median of each sample. To have a consistent result, I need an error on this difference.

It results that finding the standard deviation in such a case can be quite hard, at least for a non-pro like me (see for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59838/standard-error-of-the-median)).

I have found [this website](https://epilab.ich.ucl.ac.uk/coursematerial/statistics/non_parametric/confidence_interval.html) which says how to calculate confidence intervals for the median, even if there is no official reference quoted.

It seems reasonable to me, but I can't really judge, so I would like to know:

1. are those formulas correct?
2. There is a reference for that?
3. What about if I want to find CI different from $95\%$?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I have also found [this example of bootstrapping for non-Gaussian data](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mwaskom/Psych216/blob/master/week1_tutorial.ipynb#%284%29-Nonparametric-approaches-to-error-bars). Now, I do not know much about bootstrapping, but it would be good to have an address on its validity.

Comment: The exact sampling distribution of a sample median is derived at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45124.  (Asymptotic distributions are given in most answers, too, but those are unlikely to be relevant here.) Neither of these is the same thing as a confidence interval, though... .

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the link, but I can't catch the relation. Could you please be a bit more clear?

Comment: To find a confidence interval (CI) for a parameter, using a particular statistic, you need to know the sampling distribution of that statistic. Here you seek a CI for the population median (the parameter) based on the sample and you ask specifically concerning the sample median (a statistic). (The thread I reference addresses that latter question.) It is crucial to know the exact distribution of that statistic; from that a confidence interval procedure can be derived. The asymptotic results--on which your own reference is based--risk being poor approximations for small sample sizes.

Comment: The statistic is Poissonian. But I do not understand yet: what asymptotic result do you refer to? Are those formulas a particular case?

Comment: The formulas you link to at "this website" are based on a Normal approximation to the sampling distribution of the median, which itself is an asymptotic result.  (I have no idea to which statistic you are referring, since the only one you have mentioned is the median and there's no conceivable way "Poissonian" would apply to it.)

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the details! But they do not say so in the link, unless they use a subtle terminology I can't catch. Instead I thought they used that approach *because* they don't know the distribution... Probably I messed up with terminology: by "Poissonian statistics" I meant `Poissonian distribution`. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @whuber, I took a look at your first link, and it seems to apply only for large number of observations... which is not the case here. How do I know the statistics distribution?

Comment: I guess you have not read [my answer in that thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86804/919), then, because it gives an exact result for any number of observations: "This is an exact formula for the distribution of the median for any continuous distribution."

Comment: @whuber, yes I did it. It is a great answer, but really too much to digest, sorry. I tried to follow it, seriously, but it brings me from this to that and that to the end... I still believe, bootstrapping is the best thing here. It is independent from the distribution shape, and it seems to be used in many similar applications. Are CIs expected to be quite asymmetrical in such cases?

Comment: Bootstrapping is usually not a great idea for small samples. The theoretical justification for bootstrapping requires largish samples.

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. The samples from which extract the medians are not large, but they are many. So in the end, I have more than $100$ medians. How large should be these samples?

Comment: I don't know, because it depends on your accuracy requirements and on the underlying distributions.

Comment: I see, but then, how do we know that the sample I am using is *small*?

Answer (score 34):

#### Summary

When you can assume little or nothing about the true probability law, and can infer little about it--which is the case for small samples of $n$ observations--then **a suitably chosen pair of *order statistics* will constitute a confidence interval for the median.**  Which order statistics to choose can easily be found with a quick analysis of the Binomial$(n, 1/2)$ distribution.  There are some choices to be made in practice: these are discussed and illustrated at the end of this post.

Incidentally, the same analysis can be used to construct confidence intervals for any quantile $q$ (of which the median, corresponding to $q=50\%$, is one example).  The Binomial$(n, q)$ distribution governs the solution in this case.

#### Introduction

**Recall what a confidence interval (CI) means.**  The setting is an independent random sample $X = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ with each $X_i$ governed by the same distribution $F$.  It is assumed only that $F$ is one element of a set $\Omega$ of possible distributions.  Each of them has a median $F_{1/2}$.  For any fixed $\alpha$ between $0$ and $1$, a CI of level $\alpha$ is a pair of functions (aka "statistics"), $L$ and $U$, such that

$${\Pr}_F(L(X)\le F_{1/2} \le U(X)) \ge 1 - \alpha.$$

The right hand side is the *coverage* of the CI for the distribution $F$.

*Aside:* for this to be useful, we also prefer that (1) the infimum of the coverages over $F\in\Omega$ be as small as possible and (2) the expected length of the interval, $\mathbb{E}_F(U(X)-L(X))$, should tend to be short for all or "most" $F\in\Omega$.

#### Analysis

**Suppose we assume nothing about $\Omega$.**  In this situation we can still exploit the *order statistics*.  These are the specific values in the sorted sample.  To simplify the notation, let's sort the sample once and for all so that

$$X_1 \le X_2 \le \cdots \le X_n.$$

The value $X_i$ is the $i^\text{th}$ order statistic of the sample. Since we're assuming nothing about $\Omega$, we know nothing about $F$ at first, so we can't infer much about the likely intervals between each $X_i$ and its neighbor $X_{i+1}$.  However, we can still reason quantitatively about the individual values: **what is the chance that $X_i$ does not exceed the median of $F$?**  To figure this out, let $Y$ be a random variable governed by $F$, and let

$$\pi_F = {\Pr}_F(Y \le F_{1/2})$$

be the chance that $Y$ does not exceed the median of $F$.  Then when $X_i \le F_{1/2}$ we know (since $X_1\le \cdots \le X_i \le F_{1/2}$) that our original unordered sample of $n$ values must have contained at least $i$ values not exceeding $F_{1/2}$.

**This is a Binomial problem.**  Formally, if we define the random variable $Z$ to equal $1$ when $Y \le F_{1/2}$ and $0$ otherwise, the foregoing shows that $Z$ has a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\pi_F$. A "success" consists in observing a value at or below the median. Therefore $\Pr(X_i \gt F_{1/2})$ is given by the Binomial probability associated with fewer than $i$ successes:

$$\Pr(X_i \gt F_{1/2}) = \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{n}{j} \pi_F^j(1-\pi_F)^{n-j}.$$

You probably noticed that $\pi_F \ge 1/2$. In fact, for many distributions the two values are equal: they differ only when $F$ assigns positive probability to the median $F_{1/2}$.  To analyze the difference, write $\pi_F = 1/2 + \varepsilon$ for $\varepsilon \ge 0$.  For $2(j-1) \le n$ this implies

$$\eqalign{
\pi_F^j(1-\pi_F)^{n-j} &= (1/2+\varepsilon)^j(1/2-\varepsilon)^{n-j} = (1/2+\varepsilon)^j[(1/2-\varepsilon)^j(1/2-\varepsilon)^{n-2j}]\\
&=(1/4-\varepsilon^2)^j(1/2-\varepsilon)^{n-2j} \le (1/4)^j(1/2)^{n-2j}=2^{-n}.
}$$

Consequently, when $2(i-1) \le n$, we may get rid of the dependence of the sum on $F$, at the cost of replacing the equality by an inequality:

$$\Pr(X_i \gt F_{1/2}) \le 2^{-n}\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \binom{n}{j}.$$

Exactly the same argument (applied by reversing the order statistics) shows that when $2(i+1) \ge n$,

$$\Pr(X_i \lt F_{1/2})  \le 2^{-n}\sum_{j=i+1}^n \binom{n}{j}.$$

The right hand sides reduce to zero whenever $i \le 0$ (in the first case) or $i \ge n$ (in the second).  Therefore, *it is always possible* to find indexes $l \le u$ for which

$$\eqalign{
\Pr(X_l \gt F_{1/2} \text{ or } X_u \lt F_{1/2}) &=  \Pr(X_l \gt F_{1/2}) + \Pr( X_u \lt F_{1/2}) \\
&\le 2^{-n}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{l-1} \binom{n}{j} + \sum_{j=u+1}^n \binom{n}{j}\right).
}$$

#### Solution

This is the complement of the defining condition for a confidence interval, and therefore equivalent to it:

$$\Pr(X_l \le F_{1/2}\le X_u ) \ge  2^{-n}\sum_{j=l}^u \binom{n}{j}.$$

By selecting $l \le u$ to make the right hand side at least $1-\alpha$, we will have found a confidence interval procedure whose level is *at least* $1-\alpha$.

In other words, upon choosing such indexes $l$ and $u$, by setting $L(X) = X_l$ and $U(X) = X_u$, the interval $[L(X), U(X)]$ will be a CI for the median $F_{1/2}$ having coverage at least $1-\alpha$.  You can compute its actual coverage in terms of Binomial probabilities. This coverage will be attained for any distribution $F$ which assigns zero probability to $F_{1/2}$ (which includes all continuous distributions).  It will be exceeded by any $F$ which assigns nonzero probability to $F_{1/2}$.

#### Discussion

At this point we have some choices.  The commonest is to make the limits symmetric by setting $u$ reasonably close to $n+1-l$.  In fact, by stipulating $u=n+1-l$, the confidence limits can be found for any $n$ with a quick search or by applying the Binomial quantile function.

**For example,** let $n=10$ and $\alpha=10\%$ (to illustrate a $1-\alpha=90\%$ CI procedure).  Let's tally the lower part of the cumulative Binomial distribution with parameters $10$ and $1/2$:

```R
> i <- 0:5; names(i) <- i; print(pbinom(i, 10, 1/2), digits=1)
    0     1     2     3     4     5   
0.001 0.011 0.055 0.172 0.377 0.623
```

(This is an `R` command and its response.)  Because the value at $2$, equal to $5.5\%$, is close to $\alpha/2$, it is tempting to take $l=3$ and $u=10+1-3=8$, for then the coverage will be $1 - 0.055 - 0.055 = 0.89$ which is close to the target of $90\%$.  If you *must* achieve the desired coverage, then you need to take $l=2$ and $u=8$ or $l=3$ and $u=9$, both with coverage $1 - 0.011 - .055 = 0.935$.

As a check, let's simulate a lot of datasets from any distribution whatsoever, compute these CIs for the datasets, and tally the proportion of CIs that do cover the true median.  This `R` example uses a Normal distribution:

```R
n <- 10
n.sim <- 1e4
x <- apply(matrix(rnorm(n*n.sim), nrow=n), 2, sort)
covers <- function(x, l, u) mean(x[l, ] <= 0 & x[u, ] >= 0)
c(l3.u8=covers(x,3,8), l2.u8=covers(x,2,8), l3.u9=covers(x,3,9))
```

The output is

```R
 l3.u8  l2.u8  l3.u9 
 0.8904 0.9357 0.9319
```

The coverages agree closely with the theoretical values.

As another example, let's draw samples from a discrete distribution, such as a Poisson:

```R
lambda <- 2
x <- apply(matrix(rpois(n*n.sim, 2), nrow=n), 2, sort)
med <- round(lambda + 1/3 - 0.02/lambda)
c(l3.u8=covers(x,3,8), l2.u8=covers(x,2,8), l3.u9=covers(x,3,9))

 l3.u8  l2.u8  l3.u9 
0.9830 0.9845 0.9964
```

This time the coverages are much higher than anticipated. The reason is that there is a $27\%$ chance that a random value *equals* the median. This greatly increases the chance that the CI covers the median.  *This is not a problem or a paradox.* By definition, the coverage has to be at least $1-\alpha$ no matter what the distribution $F$ is--but it's possible (as in this case) that the coverage for *particular* distributions is substantially greater than $1-\alpha$.

**Therein lies the tradeoff:** when you assume nothing about $F$, the CI based on order statistics is the only one you can construct. Its coverage for your true (but unknown) $F$ might be quite a bit higher than you expect. That means your CI will be wider than if you had made some stronger assumptions about $\Omega$ by limiting the possibilities for $F$.

Comment: This answer focuses on question #3. As to the first two questions, (1) ("are these formulas correct?"), the answer is not quite, because they use a Normal approximation to the Binomial distribution; and (2) ("is there a reference"), the answer is perhaps, but who cares? A reference for the analysis in this answer is Hahn & Meeker, *Statistical Intervals*.

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to use numerical methods, you may generate an estimate of the samping distribution of medians by using bootstrap. Repeatedly resample your sample and compute many medians. The stdev of these medians serves as an estimate of the stdev of the sampling distribution of medians. I used a similar method to compute the uncertainty of chess game outcomes in my paper on chess gambits which may be found here https://sonoma.academia.edu/JamalMunshi/papers

Comment: This is a good idea. In light of comments to the question, what is needed is an analysis of its accuracy for small $n$. Also, there's no point to repeatedly resampling in practice because the exact distribution is easy to obtain in closed form.  For a dataset $x_1\le x_2\le\cdots\le x_n$, the chance the median of a bootstrap sample does not exceed $x$ (where $x_i \le x \lt x_{i+1}$) is the chance that at least half the sample values are in the set $\{x_1,x_2\ldots,x_i\}$. This is given by a Binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $i/n$.

Comment: @whuber, sorry, you meant "this is NOT a good idea", right?

Comment: @Py-ser The underlying idea is good in the sense that a version of it will work, but the interpretation and implementation both need improvement.

Comment: But, the whole of our past discussion was that you think bootstrapping is NOT a good idea.

Comment: @Py-ser I apologize for leaving you with an incorrect impression. It is problematic in two ways.  First, bootstrapping can work well--*in situations where it is theoretically justified.*  That requires fairly large sample sizes in general ("large" depends on the specifics of the problem).  The second way is that my comment here provides a theoretical justification *in this particular case* and that justification shows the sample size doesn't matter (because bootstrapping really doesn't accomplish anything we couldn't directly compute in a much simpler manner).