# Is this statement about the sum of quantiles correct?

Tags: quantiles, calculus

Let $X$ and $Y$ be continuous random variables both having some density, not identically distributed but independent.

Imagine I'm interested in the quantile $q_{X+Y}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Does it then hold that

$$q_{X+Y}(\alpha)=\int\limits_{-\infty} ^{\infty} f_X(x)(x+q_{Y} (\alpha)) dx$$

So the idea of this expression would be the following:

Go over all possible values of $X$.
If $X$ has some fixed value $x$, then the quantile of $X+Y$ is just the quantile of $Y$ plus some constant $x$.

But I might be very wrong in my intuition

Comment: Try constructing a counterexample.  Note that integral is equal to $EX$ plus $q_Y(\alpha)$.

Comment: @Jarle Tufto Oh damn, then my expression looks very wrong - while I look for a counter example: Would there be any similar expression that is actually correct?

Comment: Okay, already if the two distributions are normally distributed it seems to be violated

Comment: Did you delete your comment? Anyway, thanks for sharing this similar question. Now I know that quantiles seems to suck as you can't really do a lot with it unless you know the very specific distribution... :-)

Comment: Yes, there is also a good answer to a similar question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134976/compute-quantile-of-sum-of-distributions-from-particular-quantiles

Comment: Since the answer is "no," this isn't a useful way to pursue the ideas behind your question.  What do you *really* want to know?  How to find quantiles of a sum of independent random variables?  There are general formulas for that.  Or would you have two particular variables in mind?  If so, why not ask directly about them?