# Basic calculations with Order Statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, order-statistics, actuarial-science

I've come across the following problem, and I am tempted to delve into order statistics to solve this. I would greatly appreciate any help!

Suppose you draw 6 independent samples from a continuous distribution. What is the approximate probability that the population median of the distribution lies between the smallest and largest observations?

Comment: What is the probability that a sample of 6 data points are all below the population median? Do you see the next steps?

Comment: If the maximum is less than the median, then all points in the sample have to be less than the median. So (.5^6) = .015625

Comment: RIght. What's the chance that 5 are below it and 1 is above?

Comment: @Glen_b --> So, it should be 1-.5^6 = .9844?

Comment: The analysis posted in reply to a similar question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122001 provides a full answer.  Another analysis at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45124/ also answers this question.

Comment: Foxah - You found the probability that all 6 data points will be below the population median. So you also know the probability that all 6 data points will be above the population median. There is only one other pertinent possibility - that the sample range contains the median.

Comment: As so many do, you're using the word "sample" incorrectly. You draw a sample, ONE sample, of six independent observations. They're not samples; they're observations.

Comment: @Foxah my hint was an attempt to get you to spot you were just doing binomial calculations (so giving a shortcut to computing all such quantile questions)

Comment: @Glen_b - thanks for that! I actually started to head down that path after your hint. But I'm still kinda stuck, and not entirely convinced by the solution below. Will bang head against the wall a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability that the population median does **not** lie between the largest and smallest observatrions is the probability that either all of them are larger than the median or all of them are smaller. This is
$$
\left( \frac 1 2 \right)^6 + \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^6.
$$