# Confidence on the median for a weighted empirical distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, median, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I have observation data $x_1, \dots, x_n$ with associated positive weights $w_1, \dots, w_n$ such that $\sum_i w_i = 1$, representing a "weighted" empirical distribution with CDF
$$ \hat{F}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n w_i I(x_i \le x)$$
where $I$ is the indicator function. This generalizes the usual empirical distribution, which is the special case $w_i = 1/n$. Is there a closed-form expression for a confidence interval for the median in this case?

I'm aware that this question [has been answered before](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122001/confidence-intervals-for-median) for the case $w_i = 1/n$, for which the confidence interval can be obtain from the binomial distribution, but it's not obvious to me how to treat general case. I realize that bootstrap estimators are possible, but I'm interested in deriving an analytical expression, if possible.

Comment: You need to specify the distribution of the $x_i$'s to hope for a solution.

Comment: @Xi'an  Possibly, but can you show why? Given that there is a distribution-free solution for the case $w_i = 1/n$, why isn't there a solution for arbitrary $w_i$ ?

Comment: Because the weights need be connected with the distribution of the $x_i$'s.