# Two-tailed hypothesis testing with different probability tails

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, two-tailed-test

I've been thinking about statistics recently and was looking over my university notes on the course. Specifically, about two-tailed tests, I was wondering whether it was possible to have the tail probabilities to be different. For example, all the two-tailed tests specified anywhere indicate that we want to be using equal probabilities (apart from binomial tests, for example, which have the problem of discreteness and real significance levels only being of the form $1+F(x)-F(y)$ for binomial cdf, allowing unequal tails by discreteness).

By the Neymann-Pearson lemma there exists a critical region for the most powerful test of size $\leqslant \alpha$ where the probability of $\textbf{X}\in C$ under the null hypothesis is $\alpha$.

So my question is: is it technically OK to have really any critical region we want (insofar as we are restrained by interval size, and perhaps discreteness), but such asymmetrical (with regard to probability)  tails would not provide maximum power to the test (per the size/significance level of the test) and hence be less useful?

Comment: Many tests involving a discrete statistic are asymmetrical.  See my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/160148/919, especially in the "Discussion" section near the end.