# Median for Normal Distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, density-function, median

Please can someone explain the steps for deriving the probability density function of median for Normal Distribution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Standard error of the median](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59838/standard-error-of-the-median) (especially answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61759/173546) and/or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666305/standard-error-of-median

Comment: It does to some extent but my main question is how did they derive that formula for variance of median. How to obtain f(m)?

Comment: I believe the derivation of the asymptotic distribution is provided here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#The_sample_median

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Your welcome! Although the link to the Central limit theorem for sample medians above may have been more useful.