# Does the asymptotic distribution of sample median follow from statistical functionals?

Tags: convergence, median, asymptotics

I know that if $F_n$ is the empirical distribution function and $F$ is the true distribution function, then, with $T$ being any statistical functional (satisfying the von-Mises derivative conditions), the following Central Limit Theorem holds:

$$\sqrt{n}(T(F_n)-T(F))\to N(0,E\varphi^2_F(X))-----(1)$$

in distribution, where $\int\varphi_F(x)dG=T'(G-F)=\dfrac{d}{d\alpha}T(\alpha(G-F)+F)|_{\alpha=0}$ for any two distribution functions $F$ and $G$.

Here, in deriving the above asymptotic result, our $G=F_n$, the standard empirical distribution function.

If we let $G=\Delta_y$, the degenerate distribution at $y$, then the influence function is $\varphi_F(y)=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2}-\Delta_y(x_0)}{f(x_0)}$ where $x_0=F^{-1}(\dfrac{1}{2})$. Here $f=F'$ is the correct pdf.

Do these immediately tell us that $$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta_n}-x_0)\to N\left(0,\dfrac{1}{4f^2(x_0)}\right)$$ Note that $E\varphi^2_F(X)=\dfrac{1}{4f^2(x_0)}$ but I simply cannot put this value in $(1)$ because my $G$ are different. There $G=F_n$ and here $G=\Delta_y$.

Comment: I think a problem might be that the sample median is not a smooth functional - making differentiation problematic.  For example $ F_n ^{-1}(\frac {1}{2})$ may have an infinite number of solutions (as opposed to just one for $ F $

Comment: So I'll conclude that I can only say that the median has bounded influence function, unlike the mean, and therefore, the median is least affected by outliers, right? The online proofs of asymptotic distribution of sample median are based on Berry-Eseen theorem.

Comment: This thread http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45124/28746 may be of interest to you.