# Expectation of Median of Absolute Random Variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, median, loess

Let $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ from $N(0,\sigma^2)$.

What I want to get is not $E(median(|X|))$ , but $E(median(|X_1|,|X_2|,...,|X_n|))$

---

Reason why I need it is because I'm studying LOWESS, and in using bisquare wieght function, weight of residuals within the 6m(m is a median) will be 1, elsewhere its weight would be 0. And the reason why we took 6m is because, m=$\frac{2}{3}\sigma$, 6m=4$\sigma$. As $P(|Z|\ge4\sigma)$ is almost zero, weights are corresponding.

So I need a conclusion that $E(median(|X|))=\frac{2}{3}\sigma$, which I can't derive.

=============Edit================

There is a huge error in denoting $E(median(|X|))$. As I meant it by the expectation of the median of $|X_1|,|X_2|,...,|X_n|$, It should have been $E(median(|X_1|,|X_2|,...,|X_n|))$. Sorry for the confusion.

And I will also edit the title from 'Expectation of Absolute median' to 'Expectation of Median of Absolute Random Variables' (Please recommend other titles) as soon as we have the conclusion. Thank you so much for the interest.

Comment: I think there is a confusion is what you write. Can you explain in plain text what median(|X|) means to you ? Is it the median of a random variable ? Of several numbers ?

Comment: Given that he is referring to a sample of size $n$, presumably _median_ refers to the sample median. But his equations treat the median as the population median. ??

Comment: I would also note that the title: E[ absolute median ] is different to the question  E[ median( |X| ) ]. I think the author should clarify the question and resolve the inconsistencies, or that it be closed.

Comment: ... and you won't be able to, because it isn't true!  On a more helpful note, what I assume you want is the median absolute deviation from the median or mean (same for the Normal distribution).  Observe that the Normal distribution is symmetric about zero, so you don't actually need to integrate over the negative half - when you take the absolute value, it's the same as the positive half.  Have you tried integration by parts on the positive half?

Comment: I meant the median of a random variable, so $E(median(|X_i|)$. I'm still reading the comments. I will clarify my question.

Comment: Since median$|X_i|$ is a *number*, taking its expectation makes no sense. The only interpretation I have found of this question so far is to define "median$(|X|)$" to be the middle of the $n$ values $|X_1|,\ldots,|X_n|$. That's a random variable and it does have an expectation.  Could this be your meaning?

Comment: @whuber That's exactly what I meant. I figured what I was wrong. I think I should have noted like $median(|X_1|,|X_2|,...,|X_n|)$ instead of $median(|X_i|)$. I'm so sorry for the confusion. As it can be vary with the random variables $|X_1|, |X_2|,...,|X_n|$, it is a function of $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$. Maybe my equation for the expectation of should have been $\int \cdots  \int median(|x_1|,|x_2|,...,|x_n|)f(x_1,...,x_n)dx_1...dx_n$, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The OP's question is somewhat confused.
But, I think I have been able to figure out what he is asking.
We are given a parent random variable $Z \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. The pdf of $X =|Z|$ is a half-Normal with pdf say $f(x)$:

[image]

which appears thus, as parameter $\sigma$ changes:

[image]

The cdf $P(X<x)$ is:

[image]

where I am using the *mathStatica* `Prob` function to automate.

The population median is the value of $x$ such that  $P(X<x) = \frac12$, which yields:

[image]

The OP asks to show that `something` is the same as $\frac23 \sigma$. The median is NOT equal to $\frac23 \sigma$, but $\frac23 \sigma$ is a rather good simple approximation of the correct solution which we have just derived. To see this, the following diagram compares:

- the EXACT median, plotted as a function of $\sigma$ (blue curve), and the
- APPROXIMATE median $\frac23 \sigma$, plotted as a function of $\sigma$ (orange curve)

[image]

It's a nice fit  - but it is not the population median. Also note that it is a constant (a function of parameter $\sigma$) ... so there is no such meaningful thing as $E[median[X]]$ in this context.

Comment: I appreciate so much for your sincere help. As I made a huge mistake in expressing what I was curious, it is somewhat different from what I wanted. Still, I have met error function for the first time here and it is surprising that $\frac{2}{3}\sigma$ is a good approximation for the exact median. So I guess InverseErf(1/2) approximates to $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}$.

Answer (score 3):

**The constant $2/3\approx 0.66667$ in the question approximates $\Phi^{-1}(3/4) \approx 0.67449$ (the third quartile of the standard Normal distribution) as $n$ grows large.**  See equation $(3)$ below.

---

To avoid the nuisance of dealing with medians of even batches of numbers, let's focus on odd batches with $2n+1$ numbers, for which the middle value (the median) is the $n+1^\text{st}$ largest or smallest.  When those numbers are assumed identically and independently distributed according to some continuous distribution $F$ (with density $F^\prime=f$), their median is a random variable with density

$$F_{2n+1;n}(x) = \binom{2n+1}{n,\,1,\,n}F^n(x) (1-F(x))^n f(x).\tag{1}$$

(The multinomial coefficient can be computed as $\binom{2n+1}{n,\,1,\,n} = (2n+1)!/(n!1!n!)$.)

Now suppose the numbers are the absolute values of random variables having a continuous distribution $\Phi$ symmetric around $0$.  The distribution of the absolute value of such an $X$ is, by definition,

$$\eqalign{F(x) &= \Pr(|X| \le x) = \Pr(-x \le X \le x) \\&= \Pr(X \le x) - \Pr(X \lt -x) \\&= \Phi(x) - \Phi(-x) = 1-2\Phi(-x).}$$

Writing $\phi(x)$ for $\frac{d}{dx}\Phi(x)$, its density therefore is

$$f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(1-2\Phi(-x)\right) = 2\phi(-x) = 2\phi(x).$$

Plug this into $(1)$ to obtain the density of the median of $|X_1|, |X_2|, \ldots, |X_{2n+1}|$,

$$F_{2n+1;n}(x) = \binom{2n+1}{n,\,1,\,n}(1-2\Phi(-x))^n(2\Phi(-x))^n 2 \phi(x).\tag{2}$$

For the standard Normal distribution $\Phi$, the expectation of $(2)$--which is the integral of $xF_{2n+1;n}(x)$ from $0$ to $\infty$--has a convenient closed form only when $n=0$.  For larger $n$ it can readily be numerically integrated, though, because [the distribution of the median rapidly approaches Normality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86804/919) and its limiting mean must be the median of $|X|$ itself.  That median $m_{|X|}$ satisfies

$$1/2 = F_{2n+1;n}(m_{|X|}) = 1 - 2\Phi(-m_{|X|}),$$

with the unique solution

$$m_{|X|} = -\Phi^{-1}(1/4) = \Phi^{-1}(3/4),$$

the upper quartile of the standard Normal distribution.

[image: Figure]

**Computations based on $n=0, 1, \ldots, 129$ suggest a nice approximation.**  Let's compare the expectation, given by

$$E(n) = \mathbb{E}(\operatorname{median}(|X_1|,\ldots,|X_{2n+1}|) = \int_0^\infty x F_{2n+1;n}(x)dx$$

to its limiting value

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} E(n) = m_{|X|} =  \Phi^{-1}(3/4).$$

The difference is approximately $\delta(n) = 0.1043642189 / (n+1)$; that is,

$$E(n) \approx \Phi^{-1}(3/4) + \frac{0.1043642189}{n+1}.\tag{3}$$

As a demonstration, here is a plot of $1/(E(n) - \Phi^{-1}(3/4))$ against $n$ for $n=0$ through $129$.  The superimposed red line plots $1/\delta=9.58183(n+1)$ against $n$; the agreement is excellent.

[image: Figure]

Here are some of the residuals in this approximation.
$$
\begin{array}{rlll}
n & E(n) & \text{Approximation} & \text{Difference} \\
\hline \\
 0 & 0.797885 & 0.726672 & -0.0712127 \\
10 & 0.684191 & 0.683187 & -0.0010038 \\
20 & 0.679519 & 0.679234 & -0.0002850\\
30 & 0.677884 & 0.677751 & -0.0001324 \\
40 & 0.677051 & 0.676975 & -0.0000762 \\
50 &  0.676546 & 0.676497 & -0.0000494 \\
60 &  0.676208 & 0.676173 & -0.0000347 \\
70 &  0.675965 & 0.675939 & -0.0000256 \\
80 &  0.675782 & 0.675762 & -0.0000197 \\
90 &  0.675640 & 0.675624 & -0.0000156 \\
100 &  0.675526 & 0.675513 & -0.0000127 \\
110 &  0.675432 & 0.675422 & -0.0000105 \\
120 &  0.675354 & 0.675345 & -0.0000089 \\
\hline 
400 & 0.6747502 & 0.6747500 & -0.0000002 \\
1000 & 0.67459404 & 0.67459401 & -0.00000003 \\
10,000 & 0.6745001858 & 0.6745001856 & -0.0000000003
\end{array}$$

(The final value may be imprecise.)  The last three lines are extrapolations of this formula to much higher values of $n$: that they work so well suggests the constant $0.1043642189$ is accurate.

Higher-order approximations can readily be worked out.

Finally, $\sigma$ is merely a scale factor for the Normal distribution and thereby will multiply $E(n)$ when the underlying distribution is Normal$(0,\sigma)$.