# How to superimpose rotated histograms and/or bell curves on the side of a scatterplot

Tags: data-visualization, qq-plot

Does anyone know how to superimpose a rotated density plot and/or histogram on the right-hand-side of a scatter plot? I'm agnostic about what software could be used to do this...ideally it would be `R`.

My primary goal is to explain QQplots. In the one below, we have theoretical quantiles on the x-axis, and sample quantiles on the y-axis. I want to superimpose a bell curve on the x-axis, and show how each x-coordinate is a quantile, and then I want to show how each y-coordinate is a quantile on histogram/bell-curve as well. To do this I would place a histogram or bell curve on the right hand side of the plot, rotated counter-clockwise 45 degrees.

Being able to do this would help making cooler-looking trace plots for MCMC diagnostics as well. 
[image]

Comment: The last figure in my post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86804/919 used *Mathematica* for a graphic like the one you describe.  I suspect that because your question presently is software-oriented, it's likely to be closed quickly: but if you would rephrase it to ask *how to visually explain a QQ plot,* or something like that, our readers might be more forgiving.

Comment: I've written a paper on how to do this in SAS but a) Questions about coding are off topic here and b) It looks like you are using R