# Symmetric distribution with defined mean: is the median always unbiased for the mean?

Tags: estimation, inference, mean, unbiased-estimator, median

Let $X_1,\cdots,X_n\overset{iid}{\sim} F_X(x)$ be a random sample from a symmetric distribution with a defined mean. If need be, assume that $n$ is odd and that $F_X(x)$ is continuous.

Is it always the case that the empirical median is an unbiased estimator for the expected value?

Simulations suggest this is the case, and it certainly fits with my intuition, but then I go to prove it, remember the equation for the PDF of an order statistic, and do something else with my life. Perhaps I am missing a simple argument based on symmetry.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/551326/is-the-median-of-a-very-large-number-of-medians-always-equal-to-the-true-median) seems to show that what I posit is true in the limit. What about in a finite sample?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119414/prove-that-the-sample-median-is-an-unbiased-estimator) thread is helpful.

Comment: The distribution of the sample median must also be symmetric, whence the conclusion follows immediately.