# How to obtain the confidence interval for the median and for the difference in median between two groups without having the individual data

Tags: r, confidence-interval, median

With two samples `A` and `B` having `nA` and `nB` as size, `muA` and `muB` as means and `sigmaA` and `sigmaB` as standard deviations I can calculate the 95% confidence interval of each mean, but also the confidence interval of the difference between the means.

Could I do the same when the estimator is the median?
That is, summary data `Med A` and `Med B` for the respective medians, and `Q1A` and `Q1B` for first quartiles and `Q3A` and `Q3B` for the third quartiles and I also have the sizes of the samples `nA` and `nB`. Is there a formula (from these summary) allowing me to calculate the confidence intervals of the two medians but also that of their difference?  Or could I estimate it by bootstrap (with R preferably)?

Comment: Can we make any distribution assumptions such as normal distributions? Then yes. Otherwise no. Then again, why would people publish a median they had a normality assumption.

Comment: The answers are no, no, and no.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45124 for analysis and insight.

Answer (score 0):

[Anscombe’s quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) is useful here, to show that you can’t calculate anything substantial about medians from that data. These four datasets’ differences of medians, and the medians themselves, are all different even though they all have the same means and standard deviations and correlation. R gives the medians readily with `apply(anscombe, 2, median)`:

```
  x1   x2   x3   x4   y1   y2   y3   y4 
9.00 9.00 9.00 8.00 7.58 8.14 7.11 7.04
```