# Understanding that $\operatorname{COV}(X,X) = \operatorname{VAR}(X)$ intuitively

Tags: correlation, variance, covariance, intuition

I just saw [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/how-would-you-explain-covariance-to-someone-who-understands-only-the-mean) question and the wonderful accepted answer in this forum. I was then triggered to try understanding intuitively why division of $S_xS_y$ is normalizing the covariance:

$$\frac{\operatorname{COV}(X,Y)}{S_xS_y} \in [-1,1]$$

I think it will be helpful If I'll just understand why $S_xS_x$ normalize $\operatorname{COV}(X,X)$ to be $1$. Of course I understand that by definition they are equal. But my question is basically this: Using the terminology of the accepted answer, why is the total sum of red in the plot exactly $S_xS_x = \operatorname{VAR}(X)$ (more accurate, as far I understand, is to say the sum of the rectangles devided by $n^2$ should be $\operatorname{VAR}(X)$). I mean, if we take sample of $10$ observations, than we have $45$ rectangles, while using the definition, we have to find the mean of only $10$ values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This post presents a powerful method of reasoning that avoids a great deal of algebra and calculation.  To those familiar with this method, the work is so automatic and natural that one's initial response to a question like this is "it's obvious!"  But maybe it's not so obvious until you have seen the method.  Therefore, all the details are explained, step by step.

#### Background

There are several formulas for the variance of data $\mathbf{x}=x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ (with mean $\bar x = (x_1+\cdots + x_n)/n$), including

$$\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2 = \frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\right) - \bar x^2.\tag{1}$$

This determines the covariance of paired data $(x_1,y_1), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$ via

$$\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \frac{1}{4}\left(\operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) - \operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y})\right).$$

The formula implied in the referenced covariance-with-crayons post is

$$C(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n (x_j - x_i)(y_j - y_i) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^n (x_j - x_i)(y_j - y_i).\tag{2}$$

That post asserts $C$ is proportional to the covariance.  The constant of proportionality $c(n)$ could (and does) vary with $n$.  Thus, when $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{y}$ one implication of this assertion is that

$$C(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x}) = c(n) \operatorname{Var}(\mathbf{x}).$$

---

#### Analysis

Although this could be demonstrated with brute-force algebra, there's a better way: **let's exploit the fundamental properties of covariance.**  Which properties would those be?  I would like to suggest the following are basic:

1. **Location independence.**  That is, $$\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{y})$$ for any number $a$.  (The expression $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}$ refers to the dataset $x_1-a, x_2-a, \ldots, x_n-a$.)
2. **Multilinearity.** This implies $$\operatorname{Cov}(\lambda\,\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \lambda\,\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y})$$ for any number $\lambda$.  (The expression $\lambda\mathbf{x}$ refers to the dataset $\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2, \ldots, \lambda x_n$.)
3. **Symmetry.** The covariance of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ is the covariance of $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{x}$: $$\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) =\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{x}).$$
4. **Invariance under permutations.** The covariance does not change when we re-index the $(x_i, y_i)$.  Formally, $$\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x}^\sigma, \mathbf{y}^\sigma)$$ for any permutation $\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n$.  (Expressions like $\mathbf{x}^\sigma$ represent re-ordering the $x_i$ according to $\sigma$, so that $\mathbf{x}^\sigma = x_{\sigma(1)}, x_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(n)}.$)

All these properties *obviously* hold for both $\operatorname{Var}$ and $C$ from inspecting the forms of expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$.  The only one that might need any explanation is location independence.  However, a constant shift of values of the $x_i$ changes neither the residuals nor the differences:

$$x_i - \bar{x} = (x_i - a) - \overline{x - a}$$

and

$$x_j - x_i = (x_j - a) - (x_i - a).$$

Consequently, it is indeed obvious that the first version of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are location-independent.

---

#### Solution

Here, then, is the reasoning.  Because $C$ is symmetric and multilinear, it is a [quadratic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form) completely determined by coefficients $c_{ij} = c_{ji}$:

$$C(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \sum_{i, j=1}^n c_{ij}\, x_i y_j.$$

Because it is permutation-invariant, $c_{ij} = c_{i^\prime j^\prime}$ for any indices $i,j,i^\prime,j^\prime$ for which $i\ne j$ and $i^\prime \ne j^\prime$; also, $c_{ii} = c_{i^\prime i^\prime}$ for all indices $i$ and $i^\prime$.  Thus, *$C$ is determined by just two numbers,* say $c_{11}$ and $c_{12}$.  Finally, one of these numbers determines the other two by virtue of the location-invariance: that condition means

$$0 = C(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{0}) \overset{\text{location-invariance}}{=} C(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{0}) \overset{\text{symmetry}}{=} C(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{1}) \overset{\text{location-invariance}}{=} C(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{1})$$

(where "$\mathbf{0}$" and "$\mathbf{1}$" refer to constant $n$-vectors with these values).  But

$$0=C(\mathbf{1},\mathbf{1}) = \sum_{i,j}^n c_{ij} = nc_{11} + (n^2-n)c_{12},$$ determining each of $c_{11}$ and $c_{12}$ in terms of the other.

**This already proves the main point:** $C$ must be proportional to $\operatorname{Cov}$, since each is determined by any single one of their coefficients.  To find the constant of proportionality, inspect the two formulas $(1)$ and $(2)$, looking for all appearances of $x_1^2$: you can read off the associated value of $c_{11}$ from them.  From the second version of $(1)$, the coefficient of $x_1^2$ clearly is $1/n - (1/n)^2$.  From the first version of $(2)$, with $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{x}$, the coefficient of $x_1^2$ clearly is $n-1$.  (Geometrically, each point in the scatterplot of $(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})$ is paired with $n-1$ others, whence the square of its coordinate will appear $n-1$ times.) Therefore

$$c(n) = \frac{n-1}{1/n - (1/n)^2} = n^2,$$

*QED*.  This was the only calculation required to demonstrate

$$\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \frac{1}{n^2}C(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y}) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n (x_j - x_i)(y_j - y_i).$$