# The covariance of a data matrix

Tags: dataset, covariance-matrix

Please let me know if the below statement is valid or not ;

> Suppose that $X$ is an $n\times p$ data matrix with $p$ features and $n$ data samples.
> Suppose further that each feature(column) is zero centered so that the average of each column is zero.
> Then, the covariance matrix for $X$ is $\frac1nX^TX$.

It's such a simple and easy-looking question, but I had difficulty in finding the reference of the very problem.
My proof including the relevant definitions are follows.

Let
$$
X=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{11}  &\cdots&x_{1p}\\
\vdots  &\ddots&\vdots\\
x_{n1}  &\cdots&x_{np}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let the random variable $X_j$ follow the uniform distribution among the entries of the $j$th column for $j=1,2,\cdots,p$.
Then, $\mathbb E[X_j]=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ij}=0$ and the covariance $s_{jk}$ of $X_j$ and $X_k$ is
\begin{align*}
s_{jk}
&=\mathbb E[(X_j-0)(X_k-0)]\\
&=\mathbb E[X_jX_k]\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ij}x_{ik}.
\end{align*}

Now, denote the covariance matrix of $X$ by $S=[s_{jk}]_{p\times p}$.
Then

\begin{align*}
S
&=[s_{jk}]_{p\times p}\\
&=\left[\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ij}x_{ik}\right]_{p\times p}\\
&=\frac1n
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{i1}&\cdots &\sum_{i=1}^nx_{i1}x_{ip}\\
\vdots               &\ddots &\vdots\\
\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ip}x_{i1}&\cdots &\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ip}x_{ip}\\
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\frac1nX^TX
\end{align*}

Comment: This doesn't need a proof because it can be taken as a definition.  If you want to prove something, then, you must have a different definition of covariance in mind.  What is it?  Your introduction of a random variable is superfluous and the following material appears only to calculate the matrix product.

Comment: @whuber I know what the covariance of two random variable is, which is $s_{ij}$ in the above computation. But I don't know what is the defintition of the covariance matrix of a data matrix. So you are saying that $\frac1nX^TX$ is the definition of "the covariance matrix the of a data matrix $X$"? can you give me a reference for defining it? I didn't found one. wikipedia is saying about the covariance matrix of a family of random variables, not the covariance matrix of a data matrix.

Comment: One definition is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18200/919.  Two more are given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/225758/919. If you have a definition of the variance of a set of numbers, such as at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222091/919, then it implies a definition of the covariance matrix *via* the [polarization identity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142472/919).  Finally, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/ discusses the distinction between this "population variance" and the "sample variance."

Comment: @whuber thanks for your comment. I read the first three of them, written by you, not understanding the whole things thoroughly. But I'm afraid they contain quite a lot of stuffs. I know what the polarization identity is, in linear algebra sense, but understanding the whole mathematical concepts related to your answers will take several time. I just want to know if the above computation(or definition if you like) is valid or not. (I came to be nervous since your posts involve one over n squared instead of one over n.)