Does PCA maximize pairwise squared distance between projected data points?
We have a dataset of points $x_i$, where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. If we do PCA on the dataset keeping $k$ components, the resulting points $y_i \in \mathbb{R}^k$ projected onto the $k$ components maximize the squared distance of the vectors to the mean (i.e. PCA maximizes the retained variance). If the mean $\bar{x}=0$, PCA maximizes the sum of squared norms $\sum_i \|y_i \|^2$.
Intuitively, maximizing the total squared distance of the points to the mean, $\sum_i \|y_i - \bar{y} \|^2$ seems related to maximizing the pairwise squared distances between points $\sum_i \sum_j \|y_i - y_j \|^2$. I tried to see whether the two 'objectives' are equivalent by subtituting $\bar{y} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_j y_j$, but the resulting formulas are not the same, so the objectives are not equivalent. Thus, it would seem that PCA does not maximize the pairwise squared distances between points.
I am wondering, first, under what conditions the two objectives of maximizing $\sum_i \|y_i - \bar{y} \|^2$ and $\sum_i \sum_j \|y_i - y_j \|^2$ might coincide (i.e. lead to the same solution). Second, I wonder if there is some known dimensionality reduction method to maximize the pairwise squared distances rather than the variance.
Edit: Attempt to show that $\sum_i \|y_i - \bar{y} \|^2$ and $\sum_i \sum_j \|y_i - y_j \|^2$ are not the same:
$$\sum_i \|y_i - \bar{y} \|^2 =
\sum_i \|y_i - \frac{1}{n}\sum_j y_j\|^2 = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_i \|\sum_j \left( y_i - y_j \right)\|^2 
$$
The variance formula would be proportional if we could take the $\sum_j$ outside of the squared norm. But it seems like we can't:
$$\|\sum_j \left( y_i - y_j \right)\|^2 =
\langle \sum_j \left( y_i - y_j \right), \sum_k \left( y_i - y_k \right) \rangle = \\
\sum_j \|y_i - y_j \|^2 + 2 \sum_{j \neq k} \langle \left( y_i - y_j \right), \left( y_i - y_k \right) \rangle
$$
I might be missing something, but I don't see why the term $\sum_{j \neq k} \langle \left( y_i - y_j \right), \left( y_i - y_k \right) \rangle$ should be 0, as required for the variance and the pairwise squared distances to be the same.

Just to be clear: although you consistently write "distances," your formulas concern squared distances.  What PCA (based on mean-centered data) effectively maximizes is the sum of pairwise distances after projection onto a line, because that sum is directly proportional to the variance of the projected values.

Thanks. Yes, I always mean squared distances, just fixed it. I also included my attempt to show that the variance and the sum of squared distances are not proportional. Note that we're talking about the variance and squared distances for points projected onto subspaces of dimension $k$.

You may assume the data have a mean of zero.  You will then readily find the constant of proportionality is $n^2$ (when summing over all distinct pairs of data). If you don't trust the algebra, try a simulation.  Here's one in R: y <- runif(3); D <- outer(y, y, \(x,y) (x-y)^2); s1 <- sum(D[upper.tri(D)]); s2 <- mean((y - mean(y))^2); s1 / (s2 * length(y)^2)  It generates a random dataset of specified size $n$ (here, $n=3$), computes the variance in both ways, and compares them.  For algebraic details please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/222091/919.

Thanks, I had tried to set mean 0 before, but I hadn't solved the equations right. See my answer just now indeed showing that the two are proportional to one another, although with a proportionality constant of $2n$, not $n^2$

The factor of $2$ arises because you count each pair twice.  You do not see $n^2$ because you compute the sum of squared residuals rather than the variance, which involves a factor of $1/n.$  If you really view your posted answer as addressing this question, then your question is a duplicate of the thread I linked to earlier.

Yes, that's right, that's where the difference between $n^2$ and $2n$ comes from. I noted the double counting in the answer, and the sum of residuals vs variance is consistent with my original question. Although the technical content of the answer to my question and the answer in the thread might be the same, the motivation and formulation of the questions seem different to me. Even after you pointed me there it took me quite some effort to relate that question/answer to my problem, and I wouldn't have been able to find that by myself for sure.

Different motivation is not a sufficient reason for keeping threads distinct!  Your answer duplicates several ones that have already appeared here on CV.  There is value to not deleting the present thread, because it can help people search for answers, but it is not unique.  For instance, this result is basic to all K-means calculations, as pointed out (inter alia) in the answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81494/919.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The claim in the question is wrong: the pairwise squared distances between points is in fact proportional to the squared distances to the mean. Thus, PCA does maximize the sum of pairwise squared distances between points.
Following one of the comments, we can assume that the mean $\bar{y}=0$. So, the sum of squared distances to the mean is just $\sum_{i=i}^m \| y_i \|^2$. Now we want to show how this relates to $\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m \|y_i - y_j \|^2$, where $m$ is the number of data points:
\begin{align*}
\sum_i \sum_j \|y_i - y_j \|^2 &= \sum_i \sum_j \langle (y_i - y_j), (y_i - y_j) \rangle \\
&= \sum_i \sum_j \left( \langle y_i, y_i \rangle + \langle y_j, y_j \rangle - 2 \langle y_i, y_j \rangle \right) \\
&= \sum_i \sum_j \left( \|y_i \|^2 + \|y_j \|^2 - 2 \langle y_i, y_j \rangle \right) \\
&= 2m \sum_i \|y_i \|^2 - \sum_i \sum_j \langle y_i, y_j \rangle \\
&= 2m \sum_i \|y_i \|^2 - \langle \sum_i y_i, \sum_j y_j \rangle \\
&= 2m \sum_i \|y_i \|^2
\end{align*}
thus showing that the sum of all pairwise squared distances (double counting terms $\|y_i - y_j \|^2$ and $\|y_j - y_i \|^2$) is proportional to the sum of distances to the mean, with a proportionality constant $2m$ where $m$ is the number of points. Here, we just used the linearity of the inner product in several places, and in the end we used our 0-mean assumption to substitute $\sum_i y_i = 0$.
