# What are bounds for the covariance of x and min(x,y)?

Tags: variance, covariance, extreme-value

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are independently distributed according to CDFs $F_x$ and $F_y$ respectively over compact support $[0,1]$. Under what condition is $\operatorname{Cov}(x, \min\{x,y\})\gt 0$?

Comment: What does $F$ denote?

Comment: Thank you for the response - F denotes the respective CDFs. I just hoped to say both variables have compact support. I've updated the problem statement.

Comment: Under what condition could the covariance be negative?

Comment: That's my question, I guess. I am conjecturing that the covariance is always positive, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Is it correct that you are assuming that the support of $X$ and $Y$ intersect, and are continuous, as distinct from say, $X \in (\frac12,1)$ and $Y \in (0,\frac12)$

Comment: It's definitely not the case that the covariance is always positive. Take, for instance, $X$ with a uniform distribution on $[1/2,1]$ and $Y=1-X$, entailing $\min(X,Y)=Y$, whence $\operatorname{Cov}(X,\min(X,Y))=-\operatorname{Var}(X) \lt 0$. Are you perhaps assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: Nice example! Even if the intention is that $X$ and $Y$ both have strictly positive densities over (0,1), extending your example to $X \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$ and taking  $Y=1-\sqrt{X}$, the covariance will still be negative.

Comment: Right, I am assuming they are independent. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sketch of an analysis based on routine, well-known properties of covariance.

Without loss of generality, we may assume $E(X)=0$ by subtracting $E(X)$ from both $X$ and $Y$: this changes none of the second-order quantities that will appear and yields the simplified formulas $\operatorname{Var}(X)=E(X^2)$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=E(XY)$. Now apply standard formulas and break the expectation into the cases $X\le Y$ and $X\gt Y$, writing $p=\Pr(X\le Y)$:

$$\eqalign{
\operatorname{Cov}(X, \min(X,Y)) &= E(X\min(X,Y)) - E(X)E(\min(X,Y)) \\
&= E(X\min(X,Y)) \\
&= E(X\min(X,Y)|\min(X,Y)=X)\Pr(X \le Y) \\&+\quad E(X\min(X,Y)|\min(X,Y)=Y)\Pr(X \gt Y) \\
&= E(X^2)p + E(XY)(1-p) \\
&= \operatorname{Var}(X)p + \operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)(1-p).
}$$

These calculations assumed nothing beyond the existence of the variance and covariance.  When $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$.  We may conclude

> When $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$, $\operatorname{Cov}(X, \min(X,Y)) = \operatorname{Var}(X)\Pr(X \le Y),$ which is nonnegative and can equal zero only when $\Pr(X \le Y)=0$ or $\operatorname{Var}(X)=0$.

---

#### Geometrical Solution

Recall that the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, when it exists, is the sum (or integral) of positive ("red") rectangle areas minus the sum (or integral) of negative ("blue") rectangle areas, as explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18200.  **I will show that when you use your crayons to draw the red and blue regions in depicting the covariance of $X$ and $\min(X,Y)$, the amount of red you use can be no less than the amount of blue.**  This is done by comparing the picture to the one you would draw for the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ themselves.

To this end, fix $x_1 \lt x_2$.  Let $y_1\lt y_2$ be any real numbers.  In the calculation of the covariance of $X$ and $Y$, these data contribute two equiprobable rectangles: a red one and a blue one, one with vertices at $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and the other with vertices at $(x_1,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_1)$, respectively. Their areas are negatives of each other.  Their contributions therefore cancel in the calculation.  Since this is true for all such $x_1,x_2,y_1,$ and $y_2$, **the covariance of $X$ and $Y$ must be zero.**

Now let $Y$ be replaced by $\min(X,Y)$.  This changes some of the rectangles.  They both still have the same base $x_2-x_1$, but their heights change when the $y_i$ are replaced by $\min(x_j,y_i)$.  The sum of the new signed areas is

$$(x_2-x_1)(\color{red}{[\min(x_2,y_2)-\min(x_1,y_1)]} + \color{blue}{[\min(x_2,y_1)-\min(x_1,y_2)]})$$

(obtained by multiplying each base by its *signed* height and collecting the common factor $x_2-x_1$ that appears).

Rearranging the colored terms gives

$$(x_2-x_1)(\color{red}{\min(x_2,y_2)}-\color{blue}{\min(x_1,y_2)} + \color{blue}{\min(x_2,y_1)}-\color{red}{\min(x_1,y_1)}).$$

Since $x_1 \lt x_2$, $\min(x_1,y) \le \min(x_2,y)$ for all $y$.  Letting $y=y_1$ shows $(1)$ the first difference in the right hand factor is non-negative and letting $y=y_2$ shows $(2)$ the second difference is non-negative.  Therefore their sum is non-negative, whence the entire product (when multiplied by the positive value $x_2-x_1$) is non-negative.  Since this is true for all $x_1 \lt x_2$,

> **$\operatorname{Cov}(X, \min(X,Y))$ exceeds $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ by some non-negative amount.**

Moreover,

> $\operatorname{Cov}(X,\min(X,Y))$ will be strictly positive if there is a positive chance of conditions (1) or (2) above ever occurring.  This is equivalent to there being a positive chance that $Y\gt X$.

For independent $X$ and $Y$, and regardless of the compactness of their supports, these results completely characterize when the covariance of $X$ and $\min(X,Y)$ can be $0$ or positive; it can never be negative.

---

For those who might object that the "crayoning" picture of covariance applies only to finite discrete variables (or datasets), I will simply remark that you may take these pictures as accurate metaphors for the corresponding four-dimensional Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals.  (The integrand is proportional to $(x_2-x_1)(y_2-y_1)$, taken over the tuples $(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ where $x_1\lt x_2$, relative to the measure $dF_X(x_1)dF_X(x_2)dF_Y(y_1)dF_Y(y_2)$.)  The argument presented here applies to those integrals without any change: you are welcome to rewrite it in that form.