# Zero correlation between $x$ and $y = f(x)$?

Tags: correlation

Let $x,y$ be two variables that are functionally related, so that $x$ determines $y$:

$$y = f(x)$$

for some function $f$. We consider a probability distribution on $x$, $p(x)$. The question is:

Is it possible, for some probability distribution $p(x)$, that the correlation between $x$ and $y$ vanishes? That is,

$$\mathrm{cov}(x,f(x)) = \langle x f(x) \rangle - \langle x\rangle \langle f(x) \rangle = \sum_x xf(x)p(x) - \left(\sum_x xp(x)\right) \left(\sum_x f(x)p(x)\right) = 0$$

In other words, given a function $f$, is it possible to select a probability distribution $p$, such that $\mathrm{cov}(x,f(x)) = 0$?

The answer is **yes** in at least one trivial case, when $f(x) = c$ is a constant number. This case is trivial in the sense that any $p$ will do. Are there more interesting examples? Or general theorems available?

Comment: You write sums. Do you intend to restrict your question to discrete probability distribution or are answers for continuous distributions of interest, too?

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch I think sums are easier to reason about, but if you have an idea with continuous distributions feel free to contribute.

Comment: of course this is possible: let $X$ be uniform distributed on $[-1,1]$ (or $N(0,\sigma^2)$, in fact any symmetric distribution around $0$ should work), and $Y=f(X)=X^2$. you then have $$cov(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y) = E(X^3)= 1/4(-1+1)(1^2+1^2) = 0.$$

**added:** The covariance (correlation) only tells you something about a linear relationship, there are of course other relationships which are not linear and hence imply a covariance of $0$.

Comment: @EliKa Nice example. I just find it counter-intuitive, though. This is saying that even though variables $x,y$ are deterministically related, a dataset will show *zero* correlation between them.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are functional related (this does not implay, that they are necessary deterministically related: imagine a third variable, which determines in fact determines X and hence Y. beside that, see my edit in the comment (horst grünbusch's answer is just the negation: if they are linear related, then it is impossible.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**There are three mutually exclusive possibilities for $f$** (apart from the trivial one where the domain of $f$ has just one element).  To be fully general and avoid trivial complications, let's not worry about correlation, but focus on *covariance* instead: when covariance is zero, correlation is either zero or undefined.  (Correlation becomes undefined when the variance of either marginal distribution is zero.)

1. **$f$ is not injective.** Suppose there exist $x_1 \lt x_2$ for which $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.  Putting probabilities of $1/2$ on each of $x_1$ and $x_2$ gives zero covariance (and undefined correlation).
2. **$f$ is injective but not monotonic.** Otherwise suppose there exist $x_1\lt x_2 \lt x_3$ for which the $y_i=f(x_i)$ are not in order.  Since covariance does not change with translations, make the calculations easier by shifting the $x$ and $y$ coordinates so that $x_2=y_2=0$. The assumption amounts to $x_1\lt 0,$ $x_3\gt 0$, and $y_1$ and $y_3$ have the same sign. Define $C(p)$ to be the covariance achieved by putting probabilities of $p$ on $x_1$, $1/2-p$ on $x_3$, and $1/2$ on $0$. $C$ clearly is a quadratic function of $p$ and therefore is continuous.

   Compute $$C(0)=\frac{1}{4}x_3y_3,\ C(1/2)=\frac{1}{4}x_1y_1.$$ The assumptions imply $C(0)$ and $C(1/2)$ have opposite signs.  The Intermediate Value Theorem implies there is some $p\in (0,1/2)$ for which $C(p)=0$: use this value of $p$ to achieve zero covariance. The correlation will be defined and zero.
3. **$f$ is monotonic.**  Otherwise $f$ is strictly monotonic (increasing or decreasing). From the [characterization of covariance as an expected signed area,](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18200/919) it is obvious that all covariances must be strictly positive or strictly negative when the probability is not an atom.  The correlation will be defined.

Comment: "when the probability is not an atom" ... I did not understand the wording here, what do you mean by "atom"?

Comment: "probability at an atom" is the trivial random variable with $P(X=a)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no if $f$ is affine-linear. This holds by the linearity and translation invariance of the covariance.

Comment: The general answer is NO then, because not for every function you can find such probability distribution, if there's at least one for which you can't

Comment: Please, define "affine-linear" function.

Comment: Also, can you give more details about your reasoning? I am not convinced about your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Becko, this answer is correct, implicitly assuming $f$ has nonzero slope--but it only points out a special case.  "Affine-linear" means the graph of $f$ is a line.