# Concentration inequality for the sample covariance matrix

Tags: probability, covariance, random-matrix

I'd like to know if there is a concentration inequality for the sample covariance matrix that don't assume the knowledge of the true mean.

---

**Background.**

Given a probability distribution $\mu$ on $\mathbb R^d$, the covariance matrix of $\mu$ is defined as follows:
$$\Sigma := \mathbb E [(x - \bar \mu)(x -\bar \mu)^\top] $$
where $x \sim \mu$ and $\bar \mu = \mathbb E [x]$.

If $X = (x_1, \cdots x_m)$ is an i.i.d. sample drawn from $\mu$, then we can define two estimators:
\begin{align*}
& \hat \Sigma_1 := \frac1m \sum_{i=1}^m (x_i - \bar \mu)(x_i - \bar \mu)^\top, \text{ where } \bar \mu = \mathbb E_{x \sim \mu} [x] \\
& \hat \Sigma_2 := \frac1{m-1} \sum_{i=1}^m (x_i - \bar x)(x_i - \bar x)^\top, \text{ where } \bar x = \frac1m (x_1 + \cdots x_m)
\end{align*}
They both satisfy $\mathbb E_X \hat \Sigma_1 = \mathbb E_X \hat \Sigma_2 = \Sigma$.

The second estimator $\hat \Sigma_2$ is of interest because $\bar \mu$ is often not known in practice.

---

**Question.**

I'm interested in the concentration of $\hat \Sigma_2$ to $\Sigma$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$. More precisely, given a number $t > 0$, I'd like to know whether there exists a constant $A>0$ and a term $\alpha \in (0,1)$ that depend on $\mu$ and $t$ such that
$$\text{Prob}(\| \Sigma - \hat \Sigma_2 \| \ge t) \le A \cdot \alpha^m$$
where $\|\cdot \|$ is the spectral norm, also known as the 2-norm. (The Frobenius norm is also fine, since for any $d \times d$ matrix $A$, $\|A\| \le \|A\|_F \le \sqrt{d} \|A\|$)

In the case of the difference $\|\Sigma - \hat \Sigma_1\|$, such an answer can be obtained using the [matrix Bernstein inequality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01571). However, I'm less sure about $\|\Sigma - \hat \Sigma_2\|$. I have an idea, which is to use the fact that:
$$\hat \Sigma_1 - \hat \Sigma_2 = \frac1{m(m-1)} \sum_{i\neq j} (x_i-\bar\mu) (x_j-\bar\mu)^\top$$
which follows from:
\begin{align*}
 \hat \Sigma_2 =& \frac1m \sum_i x_i x_i^\top - \frac1{m(m-1)} \sum_{i\neq j} x_i x_j^\top \\
 =& \frac1m \sum_i (x_i-\bar\mu) (x_i-\bar\mu)^\top - \frac1{m(m-1)} \sum_{i\neq j} (x_i-\bar\mu) (x_j-\bar\mu)^\top \\
 =& \hat \Sigma_1 - \frac1{m(m-1)} \sum_{i\neq j} (x_i-\bar\mu) (x_j-\bar\mu)^\top
\end{align*}
But now I'm not sure how to control the sum of the quantities $(x_i-\bar\mu) (x_j-\bar\mu)^\top$, which are *not independent*.

This should be a fairly standard question with a standard answer, but I couldn't find an answer to this. A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374810/concentration-inequality-for-covariance)'s only answer wasn't addressing my question; it was addressing the case for $\hat \Sigma_1$.

I found a weak(?) answer to this question (see the [answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/389952/concentration-inequality-for-the-sample-covariance-matrix)), showing that $\| \Sigma - \hat \Sigma_2 \| \rightarrow 0$ quadratically in $m$, assuming that $\mu$ has a compact support. I think there's likely to be a sharper bound, so if anyone knows about it, please tell me.

Comment: The covariance matrix can be defined without referring to the mean.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18200/919 for a description of one way.  (You will easily see how this visual explanation translates to a mathematical formula.)

Comment: The expression $\hat \Sigma_1$ uses the true mean and the expression $\hat \Sigma_2$ uses the sample mean. I'm trying to obtain a concentration inequality for $\hat \Sigma_2$.

Comment: The point is that there are algebraically equivalent expressions for $\hat\Sigma_2$ that do not use the sample mean at all.

Comment: I see. Currently I cannot see how that would help me prove a desired concentration inequality, could you tell me how?
One expression I know for $\hat \Sigma_2$ is obtained by expanding the sample mean part, which gives $\hat \Sigma_2 = \frac1m \sum_i x_i x_i^\top - \frac1{m(m-1)} \sum_{i \neq j} x_i x_j^\top$. I wonder if this is one of the expressions you consider as relevant.