# book recommendation about statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference, references

I am taking mathematical statistics course in this semester. We learned many things such as covariance , kurtosis , skewness ,p-value,variance,standard deviation etc. We learned how to calculate them , we solved many questions .However , we did not enough pause on the meaning of them. For example, i know how to calculate correlation , but i do not know what correlation gives me , to be more specific , i do not how to interpret the value of correlation and why we need correlation. I think this is very stupid situation but it is not my fault. My professors just give the formulas not meanings.

Because of this reason , i wanted to learn them own myself. I saw that there are some videos about them on youtube , but i am a book person. So , i want you to recommend me some statistics books that gives the definitions detaily, and teach how to interpret the results . As i said , i am like a calculator that calculates the numbers but is not aware of why it is calculated.

Comment: Of course, any answers you get will be highly subjective. But you might improve chances of getting something useful to _you,_ if you tell us in what fields of application you might be most likely to use statistics. // If you're near a university library with librarians who still tolerate 'open stacks' you might go there are browse the books available.

Comment: For correlation in particular, @whuber has a terrific answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/how-would-you-explain-covariance-to-someone-who-understands-only-the-mean/18200#18200