# To calculate covariance doesn't one need to subtract the mean of the second variable?

Tags: covariance

The definition of covariance says that it is:
$cov(X,Y)=E [(X- \overline{X})(Y- \overline{Y})]$

However, it seems that we can also calculate it without subtracting the mean of the second variable:
$cov(X,Y)=E [(X- \overline{X})(Y)]$

Is this correct? My argument for discrete variables results from comparing respective sums:

I. Sum number 1:
$$\sum[(X-\overline{X})\times (Y-\overline{Y})]=\sum(XY-\overline{Y}X-\overline{X}Y+\overline{X}\overline{Y})=\sum(XY)-\overline{Y}n\overline{X}-\overline{X}n\overline{Y}+n\overline{X}\overline{Y}=\sum(XY)-2n\overline{X}\overline{Y}+ n\overline{X}\overline{Y}=\sum(XY)- n\overline{X}\overline{Y}$$

II. Sum number 2:
$$\sum[(X-\overline{X})\times Y]= \sum(XY)-\overline{X}n\overline{Y}$$

Conclusion: sum number 1 = sum number 2, so the covariance can be calculated either way.

Comment: no, $cov(,)=[(−)()]$ only if $E(Y)=0$.

Comment: If you assume unknown sample mean (which by your notation looks like to be the case), you are right, because the missing term $\sum (X - \bar X) (\bar Y)$ is zero

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18200/919 for an explanation of why you don't have to compute *either* mean.

Comment: @Firebug Thanks. I am asking about this not because in my case the sample mean of Y is unknown but rather because I encountered the term equal to the "shorter" version in a proof and I would like to interpret it as covariance which would help me to finish the proof.

Answer (score 3):

For the theoretical covariance,
\begin{aligned}
\text{Cov}(X,Y) &= \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)\cdot Y - (X-\mu_X)\cdot\mu_Y] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)\cdot Y] - \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)\cdot\mu_Y)] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)\cdot Y] - \mu_Y\cdot(\mathbb{E}[X]-\mu_X) \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)\cdot Y] - \mu_Y\cdot 0 \\
&= \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu_X)\cdot Y]. \\
\end{aligned}

For the sample covariance,
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{\text{Cov}}(X,Y) &= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})] \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\bar{X})\cdot Y_i - (X_i-\bar{X})\cdot\bar{Y}] \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\bar{X})\cdot Y_i] - \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\bar{X})\cdot\bar{Y})] \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\bar{X})\cdot Y_i] - \bar{Y}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[X_i-\bar{X}]\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\bar{X})\cdot Y_i] - \bar{Y}\cdot 0 \\
&= \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[(X_i-\bar{X})\cdot Y_i]. \\
\end{aligned}

Not subtracting the mean of the second variable works in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, this is insightful

Comment: @hamsa, I had misplaced the left large parenthesis in both instances; now fixed.

Comment: This is precise. +1.

Comment: I don't follow why it does not work for $n-1$ case, after all it's the same solution for the $n$ case, multiplied by $n/(n-1)$

Comment: I think you skipped a term in the bracket $\bar{Y}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n[X_i-\bar{X}]=\bar{Y}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}(\sum_{i=1}^n[X_i]-n\bar{X})=\bar{Y}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}(n\bar{X}-n\bar{X})=0$

Comment: @Firebug, good catch! Let me correct the answer.

Comment: @hamsa, what do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Richard's answer, it is also possible to compute the covariance without ever computing the expectation (or the sum) of either variable, just based on the differences between pairs.

Because, given $(i,j,k) \in n \times n \times n$

$$\sum_{i,j,k}(X_i-X_j)(Y_i-Y_k)=\\
\sum_{i,j,k}(X_iY_i-X_jY_i - X_iY_k+X_jY_k)=\\
\sum_{i,j,k}(X_iY_i)-\sum_{i,j,k}(X_jY_i) - \sum_{i,j,k}(X_iY_k)+\sum_{i,j,k}(X_jY_k)
$$

Going term by term:
$$
\sum_{i,j,k}(X_iY_i) = \sum_{k,j,i}(X_iY_i) = n^3E[XY]\\
\sum_{i,j,k}(X_jY_i) = \sum_{i,j,k}(X_iY_k)=\sum_{i,j,k}(X_jY_k) = n\sum_k(Y_k\sum_jX_j) = n^2E[X]\sum_kY_k=n^3E[X]E[Y]
$$

So

$$
\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i,j,k}(X_i-X_j)(Y_i-Y_k) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y] - E[X]E[Y] + E[X]E[Y]\\
\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{i,j,k}(X_i-X_j)(Y_i-Y_k) = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]
$$