# Minimum Pearson's correlation between $X$ and sign($X$)$\cdot X^2$

Tags: correlation, random-variable, covariance, moments

Suppose $X$ is a (whatever bounded or not) continuous random variable ($X$ is **not** constant) with an arbitrary distribution. Is it possible to construct a distribution s.t. $\text{Corr}(X, \text{sign}(X)\cdot X^2)=0$? If not, *approximately* what's the **minimum** (in terms of absolute values) of this correlation? Say, is it possible to achieve Pearson correlation below 0.5 for certain continuous distribution?

I read from [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452542/what-is-the-covariance-correlation-between-x-and-x2-without-assuming-norma?noredirect=1&lq=1) that $\text{Corr}(X, X^2)=0$ if $X$ is symmetric about zero, but I cannot fiture it out when $\text{sign}(X)$ is added. I tried some plots like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/297685/pearson-correlation-between-a-variable-and-its-square), but I felt the correlation is high intuitively.

Comment: Consider any distribution with a finite absolute third moment but infinite fourth moment, such as any Student t distribution having between 3 and 4 degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For any random variable (regardless continuous or discrete) that is symmetric about $0$, since $\operatorname{Cov}(X, \operatorname{sign}(X)X^2) = E[|X|^3] \geq 0$, it can be seen that the correlation of your interest is bounded below by $0$.  And since $E[|X|^3] = 0$ if and only if $|X|^3 = 0$ almost surely, that is $X = 0$ almost surely, no non-degenerate continuous random variable can attain this $0$ lower bound.

---

Your second conjecture can be negated by using whuber's comment.  Let $X \sim t_\nu$, where $\nu > 4$, it then follows by [Theorem 2.2 of MOMENTS OF STUDENT’S T-DISTRIBUTION: A UNIFIED APPROACH by
J. LARS KIRKBY, DANG H. NGUYEN, AND DUY NGUYEN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.01607.pdf) that
\begin{align*}
& \operatorname{Cov}(X, \operatorname{sign}(X)X^2) = E[|X|^3] = 
\frac{\nu^{3/2}\Gamma(\frac{\nu - 3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})}, \\
& \operatorname{Var}(X) = E[X^2] = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\nu}{\frac{\nu}{2} - 1} = \frac{\nu}{\nu - 2}, \\
& \operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{sign}(X)X^2) = E[X^4] = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{5}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}}\frac{\nu^2}{(\frac{\nu}{2} - 1)(
\frac{\nu}{2} - 2)} = \frac{3\nu^2}{(\nu - 2)(\nu - 4)}.
\end{align*}
This gives
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Corr}(X, \operatorname{sign}(X)X^2) = 
\frac{\frac{\nu^{3/2}\Gamma(\frac{\nu - 3}{2})}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})}}{\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\nu - 2}\frac{3\nu^2}{(\nu - 2)(\nu - 4)}}}
= \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu - 3}{2})(\nu - 2)(\nu - 4)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{3\pi}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})},
\end{align*}
which converges to $0$ as $\nu \to 4^+$.  This implies that there exists a distribution that gives the correlation of your interest arbitrarily close to $0$, implying that a fixed positive lower bound of this correlation does not exist.

Comment: Compute that the correlation for a Student $t(n)$ distribution is $$\frac{n-2}{(n-1)(n-3)B\left(\frac{n}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)} \sqrt{\frac{2(n-4)(n-2)}{n-1}} $$ and show the limit as $n\to 4^+$ is zero.

Comment: @whuber I appreciate your hint.  The answer was updated.

Comment: +1 It looks like your calculations are likely correct: I erred in computing the variance of $X^2$ rather than that of $\operatorname{sgn}(X)X^2.$  But it makes little difference: the point is that the variance of $X^2$ diverges as $n\to 4^+$ while the lower moments stay finite and that's enough to achieve correlations arbitrarily close to zero.

Comment: @Zhanxiong You mentioned correlation is non-zero if (non-constant) r.v. is symmetric about 0. What if the r.v. is asymmetric? Intuitively they are positively correlated, but I could not analyze it quantatively.

Comment: For the 1-st part of the answer, a r.v. $X$ is positively correlated with any increasing function of itself i.e. with $g(X)$ where $g$ is increasing (provided the variances are finite). We can take $g(x ) = \text{sgn}(x) x^2$ and I believe that the symmetry condition is not required.

Comment: If $X$ is not symmetrical, you can easily see that the covariance is indeed positive since: 
$cov(X, sg(X)X^2) = E[|X|^3] - E(X)E(sg(X) X^2) \geq E[|X|^3] - E[|X|]E[|X|^2]$. Now
$E[|X|] \leq \sqrt{E[|X|^2]}$ so $E[|X|]E[|X|^2] \leq \sqrt{E[|X|^2]^3} \leq \sqrt{E[|X|^6]} \leq E[|X|^3]$ (using twice the Jensen inequality, since the cube function is convex and the square root function is concave).

Comment: Yves, that question was asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626608.