# Books for statistical intuition?

Tags: references, intuition

I'm going to be starting stats graduate school in a bit, and as someone whose undergraduate degree didn't involve any statistics, can someone recommend a good reference on the intuition behind most of statistics? A lot of books cover the mathematical definitions, but I haven't found something that explains the intuition behind things, nor the best practices.

As an example, in econometrics, Angrist and Pischke's *Mostly Harmless Econometrics* is a book about best practices in experimental economics. Is there a similar book for statisticians?

Comment: I quite enjoyed Statistics Done Wrong: https://www.amazon.com/Statistics-Done-Wrong-Woefully-Complete/dp/1593276206/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1468952895&sr=8-1&keywords=statistics+done+wrong

Comment: Related: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29380/a-statistics-book-that-explains-using-more-images-than-equations/29392#29392. The Kennedy book mentioned there is good. Harell's Regression Modeling Strategies might also fit the bill.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "the intuition" and what "most of statistics" might be?  A huge number of books cover theory and explanations; and "most of statistics" couldn't possibly be covered in any single text.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that Harvey Motulsky's book, [Intuitive Biostatistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199946647), to be extremely well written in describing the concepts typically used in the fields of medicine and biostatistics.  This isn't a general book on statistics, but many of the methods can be generalized.  He spends time on the intuition of a given method and best practices for interpretation.