# What is sigma2 in output of MCMC regression by MCMCregress of MCMCpack package of R

Tags: regression, bayesian, multiple-regression, markov-chain-montecarlo

I am using following data and code:

```
> myiris = iris
> myiris$Species = as.numeric(iris$Species)
> head(myiris)

> MCMCregress(formula = Species ~ ., data = myiris)
> summary(MCMCregress(Species~., data=myiris))

Iterations = 1001:11000
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 1 
Sample size per chain = 10000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

                 Mean       SD  Naive SE Time-series SE
(Intercept)   1.18538 0.206918 2.069e-03      1.998e-03
Sepal.Length -0.11138 0.058294 5.829e-04      5.829e-04
Sepal.Width  -0.04027 0.060478 6.048e-04      6.397e-04
Petal.Length  0.22816 0.057331 5.733e-04      5.733e-04
Petal.Width   0.60974 0.095370 9.537e-04      9.537e-04
sigma2        0.04875 0.005833 5.833e-05      5.978e-05

2. Quantiles for each variable:

                 2.5%      25%      50%        75%    97.5%
(Intercept)   0.77743  1.04672  1.18547  1.3244075 1.586649
Sepal.Length -0.22727 -0.15082 -0.11067 -0.0721836 0.001095
Sepal.Width  -0.15863 -0.08112 -0.04035 -0.0001155 0.078274
Petal.Length  0.11611  0.18907  0.22845  0.2672629 0.339776
Petal.Width   0.42368  0.54458  0.61028  0.6739717 0.794600
sigma2        0.03853  0.04460  0.04834  0.0522567 0.061303
```

What is sigma2 in the output and what is its signficance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear regression model is

$$ y_i = X_i \beta + \varepsilon_i , \ \ \varepsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$$

so as you can see, $\sigma^2$ is error variance. On another hand, you can look at the model as

$$ y_i \sim \mathcal{N}(X_i \beta,\  \sigma^2) $$

in this case, $\sigma^2$ is a variance of distribution of $y_i$'s. So if you assume Bayesian point of view, where both you variables and parameters are random variables with a certain distributions, then $\sigma^2$ becomes an additional parameter in your model and not just "error variance" like in traditional OLS regression. In Bayesian approach you get a whole *distribution* of $y_i$'s, that is described by its mean and variance. So replying to your comment, I don't know what you mean by "ignoring" this value, but what can be said is that it is a parameter of model defined like this that describes distribution of $y_i$'s. You can read more on linear regression in Bayesian approach e.g. on [Kruschke's page](http://www.indiana.edu/~kruschke/BMLR/).

See also the JSS paper on MCMCpack ([Martin, Quinn, & Park, 2011](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v42/i09/paper)) for learning more on this library.

Comment: But it is not clear to me why sigma^2 (error variance) is listed with the variables. Can I simply ignore it while determining which variables are important for this regression. It will be good if you can provide a little explanation else your answer also looks like a comment!

Comment: @rnso I added additional clarification, hope now it gets more clear.

Comment: @rnso feel free to ask if something is still not clear.

Comment: How would you give the message of this bayesian regression in layman's terms? I can see that 2.5th and 97.5th percentiles of Petal.length and Petal.width are on one side of 0, so they are likely to be significant predictors of Species. Sepal.width and Sepal.length are overlapping 0 so they are likely to be non-significant. What would you say about sigma^2 to a lay person in simple language?

Comment: @rnso Try http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17537/understanding-variance-intuitively